# Variable sized structs with trailers

Tags: c++, data-structures

I posted on this topic [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018005/method-for-making-a-variable-size-struct) but now I have a more specific question/problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int b[];
    unsigned int t;
 } pkt;

 int main(){

    unsigned int* arr = (unsigned int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    arr[0] = 0xafbb0000;
    arr[1] = 0xafbb0001;
    arr[2] = 0xafbb0011;
    arr[3] = 0xafbb0111;
    arr[4] = 0xafbb1111;
    arr[5] = 0xafbc0000;
    arr[6] = 0xafbc0001;
    arr[7] = 0xafbc0011;
    arr[8] = 0xafbc0111;
    arr[9] = 0xafbc1111;

    pkt* p = (pkt*) malloc(sizeof(int)*13);
    p->h = 0x0905006a;

    int counter;
```

Here's what I get
        for(counter=0; counter < 10; counter++)
                p->b[counter] = arr[counter];

```
    p->t = 0x55555555;

    std::cout << "header is \n" << p->h << std::endl;
    std::cout << "body is" << std::endl;
    for(counter=0; counter < 10;++counter)
            std::cout << std::hex << *((p->b)+counter) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "trailer is \n" << p->t << std::endl;
```

}

Here's what I get

```
header is 
151322730
body is
55555555
afbb0001
afbb0011
afbb0111
afbb1111
afbc0000
afbc0001
afbc0011
afbc0111
afbc1111
trailer is 
55555555
```

*(p->b) is replaced with the trailer!  And if I remove the line where I assigned the trailer, that is p->t=0x55555555;, then the trailer and p->b are the same (afbb0000).

So my question is, how can I keep the structure define at the top the way it is and have this packet function properly.

EDIT:

I should be more clear.  I writing this for a networking application, so I have to make a packet where the output is in this exact order, I am testing this by writing to a file and doing a hex dump.  So my question really is:

How do I make a packet with a header, variable sized body, and a trailer always have this order?  The only two solutions I can think of are having many different structures, or having a vector.

That is, I could structs where

```
typedef struct{
        unsigned int h;
        unsigned int b[12];
        unsigned int t;
     } pkt1;

typedef struct{
        unsigned int h;
        unsigned int b[102];
        unsigned int t;
     } pkt2;

etc
```

or I could do

```
std::vector<unsigned int> pkt (12);
pkt[0] = header;
pkt[1] = data;
...
pkt[2]= data;
pkt[11] = trailer;
```

I don't really like either of these solutions though.  Is there a better way??

Also, this is somewhat of a separate question, I will have to do the same thing for receiving data.  It is wise to do something like cast a block of data to a vector?  I am going to be receiving the data as a void* and I will know the max length.

Comment: @devin: out of curiosity, would a union work better for you? This seems quite a skeevy abuse of language. What is the goal you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C++ solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Packet
{
public:
  Packet (int body_size) :
    m_body_size (body_size)
  {
    m_data = new int [m_body_size + 2];
  }

  ~Packet ()
  {
    delete [] m_data;
    m_data = 0;
  }

  int &Header ()
  {
    return m_data [0];
  }

  int &Trailer ()
  {
    return m_data [m_body_size + 1];
  }

  int Size ()
  {
    return m_body_size;
  }

  int *Data ()
  {
    return m_data;
  }

  int &operator [] (int index)
  {
    return m_data [index + 1];
  }

  //  helper to write class data to an output stream
  friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, Packet &packet)
  {
    out << "Header = " << packet.Header () << endl;
    out << "Data [" << packet.Size () << "]:" << endl;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < packet.Size () ; ++i)
    {
      out << "  [" << i << "] = 0x" << hex << packet [i] << endl;
    }

    out << "Trailer = " << packet.Trailer () << endl;

    return out;
  }

private:
  int
    m_body_size,
    *m_data;
};

//  simple test function for Packet class
int main ()
{
  Packet
    packet (10);

  packet.Header () = 0x0905006a;
  packet [0] = 0xafbb0000;
  packet [1] = 0xafbb0001;
  packet [2] = 0xafbb0011;
  packet [3] = 0xafbb0111;
  packet [4] = 0xafbb1111;
  packet [5] = 0xafbc0000;
  packet [6] = 0xafbc0001;
  packet [7] = 0xafbc0011;
  packet [8] = 0xafbc0111;
  packet [9] = 0xafbc1111;
  packet.Trailer () = 0x55555555;

  cout << packet;
}
```

I've not put error checking in or const accessors, you can bounds check the array access. Receiving data is straightforward:

```
Packet Read (stream in)
{
   get size of packet (exluding header/trailer)
   packet = new Packet (size)
   in.read (packet.Data, size + 2)
   return packet
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try updating the struct and then adding the following:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int* b;
    unsigned int t;
 } pkt;

...
...

pkt p;
p->b = arr
```

Here is a visual example of what it is doing...

```
|----------------------|
|     header           |
|----------------------|
|     B   int*         |  -------  p->b = arr
|----------------------|        | 
|     trailer          |        |
|----------------------|        v
                              |----------------------| 
                        arr   |                      |
                              |    B items [0 ... N] |
                              |                      |
                              |----------------------|
```

If you want to get tricky you can do something like this ...

```
|----------------------|
|     header           |
|----------------------|
|     B   int*         |  -------  (= to memory address after trailer)
|----------------------|        | 
|     trailer          |        |
|----------------------|        |
|                      | <-------
|    B items [0 ... N] |
|                      |
|----------------------|
```

Here is a working version of the later:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "malloc.h"

typedef struct{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int* b;
    unsigned int t;
 } pkt;

 int main(){

    pkt* p = (pkt*) malloc( sizeof(pkt) + sizeof(int)*10);
    p->h = 0x0905006a;
    p->b = &(p->t)+1;
    p->t = 0x55555555;

    p->b[0] = 0xafbb0000;
    p->b[1] = 0xafbb0001;
    p->b[2] = 0xafbb0011;
    p->b[3] = 0xafbb0111;
    p->b[4] = 0xafbb1111;
    p->b[5] = 0xafbc0000;
    p->b[6] = 0xafbc0001;
    p->b[7] = 0xafbc0011;
    p->b[8] = 0xafbc0111;
    p->b[9] = 0xafbc1111;

    int counter;
    printf( "header is \n" );
    printf( "%0x\n", p->h);
    printf( "body is\n" );
    for(counter=0; counter < 10;++counter)
            printf( "%0x\n", (p->b)[counter]);
    printf( "trailer is\n" );
    printf( "%0x\n", p->t );
 }
```

Comment: I like this too, but because of the application I can't use this approach.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you can't. I'm surprised that this even compiles. You're only allowed to have an array without a specified size as the last element of a struct, because of the fundamental way that structs work in C/C++.

The problem is that the compiler has to know how big b[] is in order to know where to find t in the struct. Normally it does this by looking at the array size. Since you didn't pass a size, your compiler evidently treats it as zero, which means that b[] and t are actually at the same place in memory! You need to either specify the size of b[] in the struct declaration, or you need to move t before b[].

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't compile. gcc says: *error: flexible array member not at end of struct*

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int b[];
    unsigned int t;
} pkt;
```

To

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int h;
    unsigned int *b;
    unsigned int t;
} pkt;
```

I believe it will work. That way, `b` and `t` will each take up their own space, and not the same space. You would also need to change `malloc(sizeof(int) * 13);` to `malloc(sizeof(pkt));` - the size you `malloc()` will be constant, and you'll need to `malloc()` twice - once for the `struct`, and once for the array in `b`. Of course, you're already doing that anyway, but this way you won't be wasting heap space.

If you want to use `b[]` instead of `*b` (and there are valid reasons for this), you will need to put it at the end. Sorry. That's how hacks work.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare unsigned int b[] in the struct it is not allocating any space for it.  So pkt.b and pkt.t are the same location when you dereference the struct pointer.  You could make b[] the last field in the struct.

However, if you want t to follow b then you could try this C example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define PKT_STRUCT(size) struct{unsigned int h;unsigned int b[size];unsigned int t;}

int main(void)
{

    PKT_STRUCT(10) *pkt  = malloc(sizeof(PKT_STRUCT(10)));

    pkt->h = 0x0905006a;

    pkt->b[0] = 0xafbb0000;
    pkt->b[1] = 0xafbb0001;
    pkt->b[2] = 0xafbb0011;
    pkt->b[3] = 0xafbb0111;
    pkt->b[4] = 0xafbb1111;
    pkt->b[5] = 0xafbc0000;
    pkt->b[6] = 0xafbc0001;
    pkt->b[7] = 0xafbc0011;
    pkt->b[8] = 0xafbc0111;
    pkt->b[9] = 0xafbc1111;

    pkt->t = 0x55555555;

    printf("Header:  %x\n", pkt->h);

    printf("Body:\n");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
        printf("%x\n", pkt->b[i]);

    printf("Tail:  %x\n", pkt->t);


    return 0;
}
```

This might be useful if you are working with data that is already packed.

Also you could use a union of different packet size / structures.

Comment: Doesn't compile. 

error: types may not be defined in 'sizeof' expressions.

Answer (score 1):

AS you've tagged the question C++, you could always use vector<int> instead of int []. Better still, make pkt a class and hide the internal representation from the clients. You would then have an accessor for the header and trailer and an indexer for the body.