# Allocation of memory for char array

Tags: c, memory-management

Let's say you have-

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight; 
 };
```

If you do-

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

How would C know how much memory to allocate for **name** variable as this can hold a large number of data/string? I am new to C and getting confused with memory allocation.

Comment: Don't try to write multi-language source files. I believe the idiomatic way to manage memory in C++ is with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

Comment: No, `name` is just a pointer, which has a distinct size (usually 4 or 8 bytes). Once you realize this, you got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't know, You will have to allocate memory for it separately.

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

Allocates enough memory to store an object of the type `Person`.
Inside an `Person` object the member `name` just occupies a space equivalent to size of an pointer to `char`.
The above `malloc` just allocates that much space, to be able to do anything meaningful with the member pointer you will have to allocate memory to it separately.

```
#define MAX_NAME 124
who->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NAME);
```

Now the member `name` points to an dynamic memory of size `124` byte on the heap and it can be used further.

Also, after your usage is done you will need to remember to `free` it explicitly or you will end up with a memory leak.

```
free(who->name);
free(who);
```

Comment: I assume the Q is invalidly tagged `C++` since the OP says *How would C....* and *I am new to C...* If the Q is C++, the answer is pretty similar to use an `std::string`.

Comment: I tagged it C++ because I believe they have similarity when it comes to Memory Management. Or am I wrong? I am new to C but not new to programming in general. Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: @ZiG There are indeed similarities (although you would rather use `new` over `malloc`). But in C++ you often just don't have to mess with any low-level memory management, e.g. by using `std::string` for strings, instead of plain char arrays (or pointers), or by using `std::vector` instead of self-made dynamic arrays.

Comment: @Zig And don't forget to +1 the answer if you found it that good to accept it.

Comment: `You will have to allocate memory for it separately.` Wrong. It's the _pointee_ you're allocating memory for. `name`'s memory is just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Don't assume that the memory storing the pointer for name is the same as the memory storing the data for name. Assuming a 4 byte word size, you have the following:

- `char * (4 bytes)`
- `int    (4 bytes)`
- `int    (4 bytes)`
- `int    (4 bytes)`
- `================`
- `total: 16 bytes`

which is: `sizeof(char*) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(int)`. C knows the size because you've told it the size of the elements in the struct definition.

I think what you are confused about is the following:

The contents at the `char *` will be a memory location (e.g. `0x00ffbe532`) which is where the actual string will be stored. Don't assume that the struct contents are contiguous (because of the pointer). In fact, you can be pretty sure that they won't be.

So, to reiterate, for an example `struct Person` (this is just an example, the locations won't be the same in a real program.)

- `location : [contents]`
- `0x0000   : [0x00ffbe532]`
- `0x0004   : [10]`
- `0x0008   : [3]`
- `0x000C   : [25]`
- `0x00ffbe532 : [I am a string\0]`

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` member is just a pointer. The size of a pointer varies with the underlying architecture, but is usually 4 or 8 bytes nowadays.

The data that `name` can point to (if assigned later) should be laid out in an area that does not coincide with the `struct` at all.

At the language level, the `struct` doesn't know anything about the memory that the `name` member is pointing to; you have to manage that manually.

Answer (score 2):

It allocates memory for the just the pointer to a char. You need to do a separate allocation for the contents.

There are other options although:

If you are OK with having a fixed sized maximum length, you can do:

```
struct Person {
    char name[PERSON_NAME_MAX_LENGTH+1];
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight; 
 };
```

And allocate it as in your example.

Or you can declare a [variable sized struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688471/variable-sized-struct-c), but I wouldn't recommend this as it is tricky and you cannot have more than one variable size array per struct:

```
struct Person {
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight; 
    char name[]; /*this must go at the end*/
 };
```

and then allocate it like:

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person) + sizeof(char)*(name_length+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

It will allocate 4 bytes for the `name` pointer, but no space for the "real" string. If you try to write there you will seg fault; you need to `malloc` (and `free`) it separately.

Using `string` (in C++) can save you some headache

Comment: I guess it'd allocate 8B on 64b machines :)

Answer (score 1):

For pointers the struct is allocated enough memory just for the pointer. You have to create the memory for the char* and assign the value to the struct. Assuming you had `char* name` somewhere:

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
who->name = malloc((strlen(name)+1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(who->name, name)
```

Comment: Could just use `stdup` to create `who->name`.

Comment: I presume you mean strdup? You could if it's available but it's not part of the ANSI C standard. This code example should be valid ANSI C

Comment: Never mentioned it in the question that valid ANSI C is required. Lots of implementations include this routine that may be optomised.

Comment: The version of C wasn't specified so I chose an appropriate standard.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.  You have to do that too.

```
struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
who->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16); /* for a 15+1 character array */
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a pointer to a name character array in your struct, ie. it will consume that much bytes that are needed to represent a memory address.

If you want to actually use the field, you must allocate additional memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer members occupy one word in my experience (the address on witch the data actually resides) so the size will probably be 16 bytes (assuming one word is 4 bytes)

As the man said above you need to separately allocate memory for *name witch will free memory someplace else for the size you desire

Answer (score -2):

I think you should also need to allocate memory for the name attribute