# Allocate memory for a struct with a character pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct, malloc

I was struggling to fix a code today, then I come across something similar to:

```
typedef struct {
int a; 
int b; 
int c;
int d;
char* word;
} mystruct;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    mystruct* structptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    if (structptr==NULL) {
        printf("ERROR!")
        ...
    }
    ...
    free(structptr);

    return 0;
}
```

the code was giving lots of memory errors due to the fact, that `char* word` is a string of variable length, and malloc was not allocating enough memory for it. In fact it was only allocating `20 Bytes` for the whole `struct`. Is there a way around this issue, without turning the `char*` into sth like `char word[50]`?

Comment: saw that you had a comment, but then removed it.  Please edit your question with more info or submit a second question.  There are methods to cope with a `char` vector that changes in length.

Comment: I added the comment then found the answer in the comments below. I believe, a fixed buffer size is actually the best solution since word will represent a name and names shouldn't be as long as a novel ;) . Thanks for the help. I was just really curious about allocating memory for variable strings, that's why I asked. But I was going to switch to fixed length arrays anyway.

Comment: these days space (i.e. RAM) is plentiful, so in most cases defining an array of chars as large as 1024 won't cause a problem.  I/O buffers are routinely much larger than this.

Comment: @hhachem You clearly don't understand pointers very well. Please read about pointers and arrays (for example, [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allocation of memory for char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081204/allocation-of-memory-for-char-array)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are allocating only memory for the structure itself. This includes the pointer to char, which is only 4 bytes on 32bit system, because it is part of the structure. It does NOT include memory for an unknown length of string, so if you want to have a string, you must manually allocate memory for that as well. If you are just copying a string, you can use `strdup()` which allocates and copies the string. You must still free the memory yourself though.

```
 mystruct* structptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
 structptr->word = malloc(mystringlength+1);

 ....

 free(structptr->word);
 free(structptr);
```

If you don't want to allocate memory for the string yourself, your only choice is to declare a fixed length array in your struct. Then it will be part of the structure, and `sizeof(mystruct)` will include it. If this is applicable or not, depends on your design though.

Comment: @H2CO3, I don't think Devolus appreciates your perspective.

Comment: @JackCColeman, especially since it is not very constructive to critzize wihtout any information what would be wrong.

Comment: @Devolus, to give H2CO3 credit, I think he was actually talking to hhachem or was being as sarcastic as myself!

Comment: @JackCColeman, oh! I thought he was adressing me, as it was a comment to my post. :o

Comment: The opposite is true. If the length is not known, you must dynamically allocate the memory, unless you can put an upper limit on your stringlength. Of course, you should also add code, to make sure that the fixed length is not exceeded in this cases (and don't forget to consider `0` byte) when you deal with strings. So if you say that no string can be longer then i.e. 50+1, an array is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Devolus damn, I wanted to leave this comment on the question, not on the answer! Sorry, I misplaced it.

Comment: @H2CO3, No problem, I was only confused at first. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a second `malloc` for whatever length (N) you need for `word`

```
   mystruct* structptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));

   structptr->word = malloc(sizeof(char) * N);
```

Answer (score 3):

as you can read [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/66209-struct-pointer-memory-allocation.html) you need to allocate the `char *` separately :

```
mystruct* structptr = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
structptr->word = malloc(sizeof(WhatSizeYouWant));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate memory for `structptr`, the pointer `word` in the `struct` has no valid memory to point. So you either `malloc` a piece of memory for `word`, too, or make `word` point to another character.

Answer (score 0):

malloc the outer struct will only allocate 1 byte memory pointed by `*word` since it is a 'char *' type. If you want to allocate more than 1 byte of memory pointed by `word`, there are 2 options:

1. Like what you said, declare it as `char word[50]` instead of `char *'
2. malloc/calloc (I personally prefer calloc, saving you the trouble of zeromemory, which is a very important..) the outer struct, then malloc/calloc the inner `word` as well. Remember to call `free` twice as well in this case.

Answer (score -2):

Use `word=malloc(128);`

this will allocate 128 bytes to your varible word,