# C How does Dynamic Memory allocation work

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I found the following example:

```
typedef struct {
    char * name;
    char age;
} person;

person * myperson = malloc(sizeof(person));

myperson->name = "John";
myperson->age = 27;
```

(http://www.learn-c.org/en/Dynamic_allocation)

I think im allocating 8 Bytes (sizeof(person)) in the example. So i think i blow up the program when i assign "justatestfoobar" to myperson->name...

Can someone explain why and how this works?

Comment: You are assigning a pointer to the character array literal, not the actual contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allocation of memory for char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081204/allocation-of-memory-for-char-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
 person * myperson = malloc(sizeof(person));
```

it allocates memory for the `myperson` variable (pointer), i.e, for the `myperson->name` and `myperson->age` member variable themselves.

The memory location, pointed by `myperson->name` (being a pointer), is not valid, till time. In other words, `myperson->name` itself is a valid access, but the moment you try to use the *content* of the memory location pointed by `myperson->name`, it'll be UB as the pointer value is indeternminate. You need to allocate memory separately to the pointer.

Following that,

```
 myperson->name = "John";
```

is valid, as you're storing the starting address of the *string literal* `"John"` to the pointer. After this you can *use* the pointer content. (Remember, as `myperson->name` point to a string literal, you may not change it.)

To extend this answer, let me state, if you want to *copy* a string *into* the memory location pointed by `myperson->name`, then, first, you need to allocate memory to `myperson->name` first. For example,

```
 myperson->name  = malloc(32);    //allocate memory 
 strcpy(myperson->name, "Hello");  //write to that memory
```

Comment: Yes, reason for DV? What did I miss?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I didn't downvote you, and I wouldn't, because it's a fine answer, but because the question is a pure duplicate, there are those who say we really should *not* be answering them, and there are those who believe that people who answer them anyway should be downvoted.(See this thread on meta:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315018/why-are-stack-overflow-users-more-passionate-about-stack-overflow-than-helping-p )