# Memory Allocation for Complex Data Types

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, typedef

I want to allocate memory for strucs such below

```
typedef struct {
int *buffer;
int length;
int dsn;
int handle;
} myStr;
```

which one is correct?

```
myStr *pStr = malloc(sizeof(myStr)+lenOfBuff);
```

or

```
myStr *pStr = malloc(sizeof(myStr));
```

I saw in some Examples that use the first one, but it seems a little strange for me. Does it have to allocate memory for data Buffer at the same time??

Comment: In C++, I'd discard both as wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

If you want to change the length of the buffer after creation, you need to allocate it separately. If not, you can co-allocate the two blocks in a single `malloc()` call, which might be slightly more efficient.

The co-allocation would look like so:

```
myStr * mystr_create(size_t initial_size)
{
  myStr *ptr;

  ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr + initial_size * sizeof *myStr->buffer);
  ptr->buffer = (int *) (ptr + 1);
  ptr->length = initial_size;
  ptr->dsn = ... something ...
  ptr->handle = ... something ... *

  return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to allocate memory for each data separately.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

myStr *pStr = malloc(/* ... */);
pStr->buffer = malloc(/* ... */);
```

There is an exception in C: [flexible array members](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fstrct.htm).

Comment: Sure, but I saw in embedded system programming sample that they do like above. I want to know if there is any reason

Comment: Maybe for flexible array members? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688471/variable-sized-struct-c

Comment: This is wrong.  You don't _have_ to allocate both separately, see the answer of unwind.

Comment: I'm not sure this method is stricly conforming, cause to padding bits.

Answer (score 2):

The second is correct. The first is incorrect. The data in buffer would be a separate allocation.

Sometimes you will see an array on the *last* field which is a 'clever' means to use a single allocation for the struct whereby the size passed to malloc varies according to the number of elements in the array -- you would not see this in many C++ circles. In that case, you can *get by* with only one allocation -- the following form is undefined in C++, although you will see it used and supported by some implementations:

```
struct t_array {
  size_t count;
  t_thing at[1]; // << variable length array, with t_array.count elements
};
```

In C, you could use flexible arrays, although your C++ compiler would support that feature by extension only.

Comment: Why is the first one incorrect? (Also, you cannot use indexes above 0 on a size 1 array).

Comment: Note that in C99, flexible arrays for last element where officially introduced because people used this idiom a lot. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/246977/912144).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that's not what i said

Comment: @justin Oh sorry, I meant why is the *first* one incorrect? (it isn't, see unwind's answer)

Comment: @Shahbaz the question is tagged both - flexible arrays are not supported in C++ (not sure if that changed in C++11, though)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
  int length;
  int dsn;
  int handle;
  int buffer[];
} myStr;
```

if you want to use the first case. But I strongly recommend NOT DOING THIS, if you don't know enough that you can figure why this would work.