# C++, Array adds data instead of a pointer to data

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I am working on a DLL project in C++ for a Delphi executable.
This executable has a structure like :

```
size
data[]
```

for example :

```
02 00 00 00 // Size
30 31 32 33 // data[0]
34 35 36 37 // Still data[0]
31 32 33 33 // data[1]
33 33 33 33 // Still data[1]
```

I tried by doing a class like :

```cpp
class LittleList
{
private:
    int32_t size;
    DataType* data;
}
```

and it gives me this :

```
02 00 00 00 // Size
xx xx xx xx // Pointer to data (and obviously, there are data[0] and data[1] at this address)
```

That is not what I want.

I can achieve my goal by using an array :

```cpp
class LittleList
{
private:
    int32_t size;
    DataType data[2];
}
```

but then, I am forced having a fixed length, that is still not what I want.

I thought about a dirty solution :

```cpp
class LittleList
{
private:
    char* data;
    // Storing size at data[0] ~ data[3]
    // and the actual data from data[4] to data[...]

}
```

but it would be really hard to parse, read and write.

Is there any clean solution for such a problem ?

By the way it is not a XY problem

Comment: There is no "clean" solution. Have a look here: [Variable Sized Struct C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688471/variable-sized-struct-c)

Comment: If you read binary, you also might have to handle endianess...

Comment: Both the DLL and executable are using little endian, that is not an issue. But looking at rustyx' comment, I guess I have no other choice than parsing data to char* like I was thinking. I was hoping for something simple :(

Comment: What do you mean, you don't want fixed length? Should the length be determined at run time? Or is a compile time solution possible, but you cannot type in a fixed number (templates could work in this case)?

Comment: The size must be determined at run time, yes

Comment: Do you want to `reinterpret_cast` the memory? Or copy is ok then `std::vector<DataType>` might be used.

Comment: Using reinterpret_cast is currently my solution, but do I want to use it ? I think the answer is "I don't have the choice" ! I did not understood your second sentence, but I can't use vector since it's storing datas in a pointer

Comment: Without reinterpret_cast, you might do something like: `const char data[] = "ABHello"; struct S {char a; char b; std::string s;} s{data[0], data[1], data+2};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally interpreting data, so there is a valid point to use a `reinterpret_cast` here. Don't be too afraid of Undefined Behavior - using Delphi is Undefined Behavior per se.

The easiest way seems to be a

```
private:
DataType& at(size_t i) { 
  assert(i<size);
  return reinterpret_cast<DataType*>(&size+1)[i];
}
```

which you then use as a building block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is indeed my (I was hoping temporary) solution, so I guess there is no way of doing what I wanted to achieve first : adding data right in the class, even as the latest member instead of adding data to a pointer ?

Comment: @Nox: The easiest way to understand your problem is `sizeof(LittleList)`. In C++, `sizeof` is a compile-time constant.