# Struct declaration WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK Network[1];

Tags: c, struct

Given this struct:

```
typedef struct _WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST {
    WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK Network[1];
} *PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST;
```

What does the declaration `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK Network[1]` mean?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK` is but my first guess it is to emulate passing references without flooding code with `&`, similar to what `gmp` does.

Comment: @pmr, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707403(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks likely that `Network` is intended to serve as a [flexible array member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad).  By over-allocating the struct by `sizeof(Network) * (n - 1)` bytes, the library and client code can access past the end of the struct as if the array member was `n` elements long.

Library code:

```
PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST list = malloc(sizeof(_WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST)
    + (sizeof(WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK) * (n - 1)));
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    list->Network[i] = ...;
}
```

Client code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    do_something(list->Network[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was about to type this. The function [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749.aspx)  only ever gives the caller back a pointer to the struct, which has a count of the items in the array as another member.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef struct _WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST {` declaring a struct named `_wlan...list`

`WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK Network[1];` assumes a struct called `WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK` is declared somewhere. It is an array of length 1 (pointless) and called Network.

`} *PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST;` instantly creates a (pointer) variable of this struct called `pwlan...list`

Comment: yeah may be pointer variable can points to some variable memory later by allocating, and by using that array variable we can use accordingly.. thank you