# why char buf[] instead of char *buf in redis's sdahdr struct

Tags: c, redis

In redis there is a struct called `sdahdr`:

```
struct sdahdr
{
int len;
int free;
char buf[];
}
```

Why not use `char *buf` instead, and why is `sizeof(sdahdr) == 8` instead of 12?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310207/what-are-the-real-benefits-of-flexible-array-member/20310321#20310321, see linked questions also

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the whole thing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char  buf[]` is a placeholder for a string. Since the max length of the string is not known at compiletime, the struct reserves the name for it, so it can be properly adressed.

When memory is allocated at runtime, the allocation must include the length of the string plus the sizeof the struct, and then can pass around the structure with the string, accessible via the array.

```
 char *s = "test";
 struct sdahdr *p = malloc(sizeof(struct sdahdr)+strlen(s)+1);
 strcpy(p->buf, s);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, And I am wondering if I can only user struct sdahdr *p instead of struct sdahdr p, the latter form can't be well addressed at buf?

Comment: You'r welcome. Would be nice to accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @Xpray there is also an official documentation called [Hacking Strings](http://redis.io/topics/internals-sds) that you may want to browse in addition.