# How do I pass a size of an array in a struct from a user input

Tags: c, struct

I got an assignment where I need to send an array of size N randomly generated numbers to a msg queue, msg queues need to be used with structs but how can I define the size of array in said struct from user input?

```
struct my_msg {
  long int msg_type;
  char some_text[];
```

so to be more specific lets say user enters 7 as the size of the array how do I make it into some_text[7] but after already defining the struct?

Comment: Why must the struct already be defined? … or is this an assumption?

Comment: @S3DEV arent we supposed to always define structs that we will be using in code at the beginning before main func? and I'm scanf-ing the user input in main so I cant pass it to an already defined object

Comment: You could either use a pointer or [flexible array memeber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310207/what-are-the-real-benefits-of-flexible-array-member) and then allocate the wanted memory

Comment: @Bob__ would it be somethhing like this?```struct my_msg* Message = malloc(sizeof(struct Message) + size * sizeof(int));```

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, if you want to use a FAM. Have your teachers already taught you that, though?

Comment: @HashemTouqan That might waste memory because `sizeof(struct Message)` includes padding. The `some_text` is also `char`, not `int`. Your size will also not be suitable to allocate an array, if that is desired. The size is `size_t size = offsetof(struct Message, some_text) + text_size;` for a single message and `size = (size + _Alignof(struct Message) - 1) & ~(_Alignof(struct Message) - 1);` to correct for arrays.