# Returning a bigger type of date from a function with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get a file’s size in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c)

I have a function in C that is reading an unknown number of rows from a text file.
I'm inserting the data from the row to a `struct` I have.
Each line i'm increasing the size of the struct with `realloc`.
All is fine, but the function returns this `struct` and should be inserted to "main" `struct` of the program. From my way of thinking, it should not work, and it doesn't.
I don't know how much space I should allocate to the main `struct`, and then i'm trying to compare a bigger `struct`.

The code is very long, but this is what i'm doing basically:

```
int* blah()
{
    int *x;
    x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
    x[3]=3;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int *y, *z;
    y=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*1);
    z=y;
    z = blah();
 return 0;
}
```

How can I know how much I should increase the `y` ?

p.s
If I doing a `malloc` of 10 and there are 5 lines in the file, it's working (as I expect).

Thanks

**Edit:**
This program that I'm building is for school, and I was given the prototype of the function that reads, and it only returns the struct and gets a pointer to the file. So I can't send more variables.

**Edit 2:**
The structs:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
}POINT;

typedef struct
{
    POINT points[SHAPE_TYPE];
}POLIGON;

typedef struct
{
    POLIGON poly;
    float sides[SHAPE_TYPE];
}RECORD;
```

the read function:

```
RECORD* Read(FILE* F)
{
    RECORD* rec;
    int i=1,j;

    rec = (RECORD*)malloc(PACK*sizeof(RECORD));

        if (rec == NULL) 
        {
                   exit(1); 
        }

    rec[0].poly.points[0].x=0;

    if(F == NULL)
    {
         printf("Could not open a file for reading. Exiting....\n");
         exit(1);
    }


         while (!feof(F))
         {
             if(rec[0].poly.points[0].x==(sizeof(*rec)/sizeof(RECORD)-1))
                rec = (RECORD*)realloc(rec,((sizeof(*rec)/sizeof(RECORD))+PACK)*sizeof(RECORD));

                if (rec == NULL) {
                   exit(1); 
                }

             for(j=0; j<SHAPE_TYPE; j++)
                fscanf(F, "%d,%d,%f,",&rec[i].poly.points[j].x,&rec[i].poly.points[j].y,&rec[i].sides[j]);

             fscanf(F,"\n");

             rec[0].poly.points[0].x=i;

             i++;
         }

      fclose(F);

         return rec;

}
```

I call it like this:

```
RECORD* rec,p;
FILE *f;

rec = (RECORD*)malloc(PACK*sizeof(RECORD));

p=rec;

f=NULL;
f = fopen("Save.txt", "r");

p = Read(f);
```

I can't use global variables.
`PACK` - const number. I should increase the array with this number.
`SHAPE_TYPE` - Const - the number of points the polygon has.

in the first cell in the array -> `rec.[0].poly.points[0].x` - this is where I should save the numbers of actually `RECORD`s in the array, so I'm starting to fill it from [1].

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create an `array` of `RECORD` in the `main()` and then read from the file with a function that create another unknown sized array and returns a pointer of `RECORD` (array).

The easy way is to send the pointer array from the main to the function and to return nothing (void) but I have forced to use this prototype.

Comment: There are, unfortunately, no structures in your stripped down model (and a few memory leaks, but I'm assuming you're more concerned about expansion right now and those leaks are side-effects of the code-stripping). If possible, can you elaborate on the initial allocation (including the struct definition) in `main()` as well as a little more detail on how it should expand in your reader-function? I *think* this is doable by simply passing the initial allocation into your reader, and letting *it* expand it as needed.

Comment: Yes I know there are no structures, I was trying to make the same mistake I am doing in my original program (I don't think it has something to do with the struct) I know I didn't use `free()` here in my example.
There are few structures, one inside another one and It will be very long and not very readable if I post all here, so I'm trying to make the same actions but with this `int`.

Comment: No worries. Is the *thing* being read from the file supposed to be "compared" (binary, item by item, whatever) with the *thing* allocated in main? is that the dilemma ?

Comment: Why do you need to have the data in `main`? Why not just a pointer?

Comment: I'm creating a structure in the main. I'm calling to a functions that reads from a file and building an array of structures, and returning it (as a pointer).
I want to structure value that I created in the main will be the the structure I'm returning from the function.

Comment: (a) is the structure in `main()` the same *kind* of structure as that built **independently** in your file-read? (b) I'm not clear what "I want to structure value that I created in the main will be the the structureI'm returning from the function" even means. You want whatever you allocate in `main()` *before* the file-read even happens to be the *same* as the result of the file-read *after* it happens?

Comment: After seeing your edit, this officially makes no sense with the data we've been given (as if it made much before that). Without some way of `main()` knowing how *big* the structure (whose actual definition is still a mystery to us) list allocated in `blah()` is, there is no way you can even use it post-return from `blah()` (since you don't know where it ends) much less allocate a something of comparable size (of an unknown). Either we need a *much* more concrete definition of the problem or this is going to wind up in the close-basket.

Comment: BTW: `x[3]=3;` is off by one.

Comment: yep it should be x[2]**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that instead of `struct` you mean array of `struct`'s (or your `struct` holds an array of rows) since I don't know how one can dynamically increase the size of a structure in C (**edit**:  see WhozCraig's comment below).

You can pass your array to the function and extend it (using `realloc`) if necessary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *blah(int *arr, size_t *elem_count, size_t *max_size)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
    {
        if((*elem_count) == (*max_size)) /* max capacity exceeded */
        {
            int *tmp;
            ++(*max_size);
            tmp = realloc(arr, *max_size * sizeof *arr);
            if(tmp == NULL)
            {
                ;               /* Error handling and cleanup */
            }
            arr = tmp;
        }
        arr[(*elem_count)++] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *arr = NULL;
    size_t count = 0, size = 0, i;
    /* You may also pass an allocated array to `blah' */
    arr = blah(arr, &count, &size);
    if(arr == NULL)
    {
        ;                       /* Error handling and cleanup */
    }

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);

    free(arr);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You also have to pass two more pointers to be able to control the capacity of your array and the number of items it currently holds.

**PS**. C allocation functions don't require the explicit cast of the return values.

Comment: In C you *can* expand a structure by using a flexible array member (which always must be the *last* member). One such example with proposed manufacturing techniques is mentioned [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad). Its been around a long time, though the syntax has changed a little over the standard releases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the "old z" to your function, and then use "realloc" - you will also need a "current count" so that you know what size to extend to:

```
int* blah(int *old, int* count)
{
    int *x;
    *count += 3;     // add three to count, as we are adding three elemnts
    x=realloc(old, sizeof(int)*count);
    if (!x) {
        free(old);   // Prevent leaking the "old" pointer. 
        allocation_failed();   // Do something if this goes wrong!
    }
    x[count-3]=1;
    x[count-2]=2;
    x[count-1]=3;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int *z = NULL;   // initialize z to NULL so we can start from "empty".
    int i;
    int count = 0; 
    z = blah(z, &count);
    z = blah(z, &count);
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
      printf("%d\n", z[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing a pointer to `count`, that way we can update count for each call to `blah`.

There are clearly any number of other ways that this problem could be solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
This program that I'm building is for school, and I was given the prototype of the function that reads, and it only returns the `struct`, and gets a pointer to the file. So I can't send more variables.

Comment: Then we need to see more of the code - or you'll have to solve the problem in a different way (that is, keep the count outside of the function) - or you've been set an impossible task, which seems unlikely.

Comment: If it's suitable you can do all allocations inside `blah` function marking the end of your array with the specific value (as '\0' marks the end of null-terminated strings). Also you may use global variables, but it's bad design (in general)

Comment: @MatsPetersson I've a sneaking suspicion this is a flexible-array problem with the array content being of one structure-type, and the head structure holding the array containing all the size information, etc. But since we've not seen anything resembling an actual structure we may never know.

Comment: That's why I said we need to see more of the code in the actual problem setting - we can only guess, and guessing doesn't really work that reliably!

Comment: I updated the thread with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was something with the `realloc`.

I'm not sure that all of my code is written correctly, but I change the `realloc` to:

```
        if(((*REC)[0].poly.points[0].x+1) % PACK==0)
        {
            p = (RECORD*)realloc(p,((*REC)[0].poly.points[0].x+1+PACK)*sizeof(RECORD));

                if (p == NULL) 
                {
                   exit(1); 
                }
        }
```

And now it's working..