# What's the difference between char [] and char * in struct?

Tags: c

There is a struct like this:

```
struct sdshdr {
    int len;
    int free;
    char buf[];
};
```

And the result of `printf ("%d\n", sizeof(struct sdshdr));`is 8. If I change `char buf[]` to `char *`， the result would be 16. Why is `char buf[]` taking no space here(`sizeof(int)` is 4)？ When shoud I choose `char buf[]` over `char *buf`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flexible array members in C - bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct with the empty brackets `[]` is allowed as the last element of the `struct`. It lets you allocate additional space beyond `sizeof(sdshdr)` for the elements of the array, letting you embed the array data with the array itself.

Pointers, on the other hand, store the data in a separately managed segment of memory, and require an additional call to `free` at the end. Unlike the `[]` way, pointers let you have more than one variable-length array inside the same `struct`, and the element can be placed anywhere in the `struct`, not only at the end of the `struct`.

Comment: An example of what exactly that additional call to `free` at the end looks like would be a really good addition to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Taking "`char[]`" more generally:

`char[]` will actually allocate a number of characters inside the struct. (A struct with `char x[17]` will grow by 17 bytes and so on.) A `char*` will just hold a pointer.

An actual `char x[]` (with no size specified - and I think the same goes for size 0) at the end of the struct is a special case called a "flexible array member" and is discussed in the linked question and in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember also that `sizeof` needs to be determined at compile time. Since `char buf[]` is a flexible array member it's size cannot be known at compile time, therefore will be omitted from the calculation of `sizeof`.

`char *` is a pointer to a char variable, and it's size is known so is included (however that is the size of the pointer not the array it points to).