# typedef for an array of structures with one char array as member for structure

Tags: c++, c, struct, typedef, oracle-pro-c

I usually declare variable in oracle-pro *c/c++ by

```
VARCHAR myvar[25];
```

After precompilation of my file changes to like this

```
typedef struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[1]; } VARCHAR;
struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[25]; } myvar;
```

Since typedef is given for `varchar` when we use the `varchar myvar[25]` statement,

1. why it does not create the array of structures `myvar[25]` ?
2. How `arr[1]` in typedef statement changed to `arr[25]` in second line?

Comment: 1) `myvar` : Duplicate names.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sorry. I cannot catch you

Answer (score 1):

From the precompiled code you showed, I would say that

```
VARCHAR myvar[25];
```

is interpreted like this SQL

```
myvar varchar(25)
```

which is also what is generated, notice `char arr[25]`

```
struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[25]; } myvar;
```

Comment: If it really want to interpret as you said above.. whats the need for this statement `typedef struct { unsigned short len; unsigned char arr[1]; } VARCHAR; `. Please clarify. I want to know is there is any concept in c which makes like this. If it is work of precompiler there is no issue

Comment: I don't know, what the `VARCHAR` typedef is for. In C, you can use such minimal typedefs, when you allocate dynamic memory. You can say `p = malloc(sizeof(VARCHAR) + 14)`, which gives you a varchar of size 14 on the heap. But since I have neither written the precompiler, nor access to the precompiler's documentation, I cannot say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. `myvar` is an object, which reserves memory for the array for characters `myvar.arr[25]` and string length `myvar.len`. What else would it need?
2. That is probably a [struct hack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553542/694733). I would guess it's used to create a generic VARCHAR pointers.

Example:

```
void PrintVarChar(VARCHAR * vcPtr) {
    for(unsigned short i; i < vcPtr->len; ++i) {
        PrintChar(vcPtr->arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
PrintVarChar((VARCHAR*)&myvar);
```

Comment: Struct hack is interesting... But It seems to be undefined behaviour.. How the undefined behavior will be used by oracle precompiler?

Comment: Well, I didn't say it was a good and portable practice :) Why does Oracle use it? Only they could tell.