# How to increase the size of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array inside a structure as below

```
struct st
{
    ....

    int index[1];

    ....
}
```

How can I increase size of the array present inside structure to say 6, when I want to use the array inside a function.

Comment: Do you want to set different sizes at compile time or do you need to resize the array dynamically at run time?

Comment: during compile time it self. My scenario is I got one structure from the existing code and I need to increase capacity of array present in the structure from 1 to 6 for my use.

Comment: Then, why don't you just change the array size in the declaration, say `int index[6];`?

Comment: I cant change it, it is the common API code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you looking for [struct hack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553542/2549281). Struct hack is a technique which allows you allocate additional memory for an array inside struct. Here is an example

```
struct str {
    int value;
    char ar[0];
};


int main()
{

   struct str *s = malloc( sizeof(struct str) + 20 );
   strncpy( s->ar,"abcd", 5);
   printf("%s",s->ar);
   return 0;
 }
```

As array defined at the end of the struct, `s->ar` will get those additional 20 bytes added to `sizeof(struct str)`  in `malloc`.

**Edit** as  Daan Timmer noted, this technique can be applied only to last member of a struct.

Comment: Do note: the `char ar[0]` has to be at the end (bottom) of the structure.

Comment: @DaanTimmer I mentioned that array is at the end of struct, but I added a note to emphasis this point

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
struct st { ....

int index[6];

....
}
```

Also you may check function  `malloc()` and [realloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) in C

**On a side note:**

You may check  STL container like [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which encapsulate the associated memory management.

Comment: STL containers don't apply to applications written in `C`.

Comment: @moooeeeep:- Yes I understand that. Thats why ihave written it on a side note! But thanks for pointing that!

Comment: I have an existing structure which has array of size 1. Now I need to increase its size.

Comment: @PhalgunSirga:- Yes thats what realloc and malloc are used for!

Answer (score 1):

An array defined that way exists on the stack. In order to dynamically change the size you will need to use allocate on the heap using `malloc` `realloc` and `free`.

Comment: What do you mean by "exists on the stack" ? Structures and fixed length array can live on the heap too !

Comment: Some further reading I found out globals such as OP's can live on either, or somewhere else, implementation specific. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You can also allocate a fixed length array on the heap : int (*my_array)[10] = malloc(sizeof *my_array);