# Unknown size of int array

Tags: c, pointers

I have a `struct` which contains an array of `int`s. I do not want to fix the size of the array as I don't know how many elements will go into it and do not want to waste memory.

An array of int pointers would be the same essentially.

I tried a pointer to an array of integers and a double pointer to no avail.

How could I accomplish this?

NOTE:

What I mean by array of int pointers is that if I set a fixed size array of int pointers then I am still wasting space, so in that sense it makes no difference with a fixed size array of `int`s. The only difference is that an `int` and `int pointer` may be different in size.

Comment: It's pointless to have an array of int pointers instead of an array of ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> An array of int pointers would be the same essentially.

No, you mean a pointer (`int *`):

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
```

If you don't know `n` beforehand:

```
int n = 0, *arr = NULL;

while (condition) {
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
    n++;
}
```

Comment: I don't know `n` beforehand though.

Comment: I want to grow the array like a `vector`.

Comment: @Zaphod: That's what dynamic memory is all about.  If you want that sort of data structure than you can A) implement it, or B) find an existing implementation. Nothing in standard C will do this for you.

Comment: But you do will know 'n' (number of array elements) runtime right ??

Comment: @Zaphod Are you asking for a linked list?

Comment: @Zaphod: It is not possible to have an array and at the same time not to know the number of elements. It is self-contradictory. The number of elements can change at run-time, but an any given moment it must be a specific number.

Comment: @AndreyT. Sure, but that's not the point. The point is I do not want to fix the number initially.

Comment: @Zaphod: You don't have to *fix* it neither initially nor at any other moment. This means that at any run-time moment you can increase it or decrease it using `realloc`. That's the only way "not to fix" the array size in C. Yet at any moment (including "initially") the array will have to have a specific size. Which means that you will have to *choose* some initial size in any case. Later you will be able to change it if it proves insufficient (or excessive).

Comment: @AndreyT. I ended up doing slightly different but yes, `realloc` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> An array of int pointers would be the same essentially

Not really. An array of pointers has absolutely nothing to do with it.

What you need is an `int *a` pointer, which you will use as a pointer to the first element of an array of integers. That array of integers you will allocate yourself at run-time thorough `malloc` with appropriate size. You will be able to grow your array, if the need arises, using `realloc`.

If your struct type has only one run-time-sized array in it, you have another option known as a "struct hack". There is plenty of information on "struct hack" that you can search for. Here's one example: [C struct hack at work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542/c-struct-hack-at-work)

Comment: You're saying something like `int (*a)[100]`?

Comment: @Zaphod: No, he's saying `int *a`

Comment: No. This is a pointer to an array of *fixed* compile-time size `100`. You said that your array size is unknown at compile time. For that you need `int *a` specifically and a `malloc` of appropriate size. Later you will access it as `a[i]`.

Comment: @Zaphod: Exactly. That pointer will point to the element number `0` of your run-time allocated array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
struct stuff
{
  int arr[1];
};
```

Then when you create one of these, you use `malloc(sizeof(struct stuff) + n*sizeof(int))` where `n` is how many extra integers you want to store.  Then you can access them as usual, e.g. `mystuff.arr[100]` so long as `n` was at least 100.

In C99 you can instead say `int arr[];` and prior to C99 if you have GCC you can do `int arr[0];`.  This of course makes it easier to create empty arrays if you want that.