# Fixing size of array as opposed to using a pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I have an array and all I have is an upper limit on how big the array can get, and if the number of elements that get added can be considerably smaller than this limit, is it always the right choice to declare a pointer and just reallocate extra memory whenever the array grows?

For instance, instead of declaring `int a[max]` I can declare a pointer `int *a` and than just `realloc` when I add elements. This would save memory. Is there any drawback to doing this?

Comment: What if realloc fails? You should profile the performance on target with actual application before making your mind.

Comment: @MohitJain. Oh I see, I did not think of failure.

Comment: "This would save memory. Is there any drawback to doing this?" -- Of course; there's a time/space tradeoff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unknown size of int array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375137/unknown-size-of-int-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some drawbacks:

- increased code complexity
- additional failure  cases (`realloc` might fail)
- possible performance loss (`realloc` can be slow if the array has to be moved)

You have to check and decide if the drawbacks outweigh the benefit of using less resources in most cases. Another advantage is that you don't have to know a maximum array size in advance.

Comment: I was aware of the possible performance loss but just always took for granted that the call will succeed.

Comment: @Zaphod Unless you're working in a highly memory constrained environment or your max size is huge, it's reasonable to assume that the realloc will succeed (and to exit the program if it doesn't) ... after all, you assume that the static array allocation will succeed, but that can fail just as well (in which case your program won't load).

Answer (score 2):

Calling `realloc` on every append to your array is probably too expensive. You should keep the allocated size of your memory zone, and increase it once in a while. If `oldsize` is the old size, you might compute something like `newsize = (5*oldsize/4+10)|0xf;` since for small sizes this would grow by at least 10 elements, and for large sizes you won't lose more than about 25% of memory.

If speed is a concern, you might special-case the common small sizes, e.g. by declaring a *local* array `int loc[8];` and use `loc` instead of a `malloc`-ed or `calloc`-ed pointer for small arrays of size <=8. You could also consider [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) to allocate some *small* array on the stack (don't use `alloca` on more than a few dozens of kilobytes on current desktops), or use [VLAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You might also consider flexible array members.

Of course you should always test against failure of calls to `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` etc.... (and in general of every library function you are using). Read carefully the documentation of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might save memory but you will certainly affect the performances.

If you want to store elements but you does not know a priori how much, why don't you use [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) ?

Comment: This might be more efficient for adding (+ realloc), but access to the list is typically much slower. Depends on the usage, of course.

Comment: It depends on how you intend to handle it (and we have no clue here). But from a memory management POV at least it is simpler.

Comment: The OP wrote "I have an array". A linked list is not an array, and there aren't very many use cases where they are interchangeable.

Comment: reallocing an array to a new size is simpler than adding a node to a linked list and is far more memory-efficient.

Comment: Maybe OP has an array because he didn't thought about alternatives, that is why I suggested linked list. Since we don't know how OP would use it, it is hard to make any assumption about the interchangeability and the efficiency of adding/removing/moving elements in the data structure without being opinion-based.