# Initialize private array with unknown number of elements (C++98)

Tags: c++, arrays

Looks like I missed something fundamental here, but haven't worked it out.

Below is a snippet and its corresponding output.

What I wanted to do is:
 - Declare and initialize an array of structs, without knowing the number of elements in advance.
 - Ideally the array itself and its number of elements are *private* members.

What I tried:

- Declared `m_member_tab[]` and `m_num_members` as private.
- Created an `Init()` function that initializes `m_member_tab[]` and calculate `m_num_members`.

Outcome:

- `m_member_tab[]` is initialized ok (see below output).
- BUT inside the constructor (after calling `Init`), `m_member_tab` is corrupted.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using std::cout; using std::endl;

  class TArrayTest
  {
      public:
          TArrayTest();

      private:
          void Init();

          typedef struct _TMember
          {
              int m_key;
              int m_val;
          }
          TMember;

          TMember m_member_tab[];
          int m_num_members;
  };

  TArrayTest::TArrayTest()
  {
      Init();
      cout << "Ctor: Number of elements = " << m_num_members << endl;
      for( int i = 0; i < m_num_members; i++ )
      {
          cout << "Ctor: "
              << "key " << m_member_tab[i].m_key
              << " - val " << m_member_tab[i].m_val
              << endl;
      }
  };

  void TArrayTest::Init()
  {
      TMember m_member_tab[] =
      {
          { 1, 100 },
          { 2, 200 },
          { 3, 300 },
          { 4, 400 },
          { 5, 500 },
      };
      m_num_members = sizeof( m_member_tab ) / sizeof( TMember );
      cout << "Init: Number of elements = " << m_num_members << endl;
      for( int i = 0; i < m_num_members; i++ )
      {
          cout << "Init: "
              << "key " << m_member_tab[i].m_key
              << " - val " << m_member_tab[i].m_val
              << endl;
      }
  }

  int main()
  {
      TArrayTest test;
  }
  ```

Output:

```
    Init: Number of elements = 5
    Init: key 1 - val 100
    Init: key 2 - val 200
    Init: key 3 - val 300
    Init: key 4 - val 400
    Init: key 5 - val 500
    Ctor: Number of elements = 5
    Ctor: key 5 - val 32766
    Ctor: key 0 - val 0
    Ctor: key 0 - val 0
    Ctor: key -1212526907 - val 32623
    Ctor: key 0 - val 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This member declaration:

```
    TMember m_member_tab[];
```

is not valid C++.

There is an additional problem in the `init` function, where you declare a local variable of the same name, but it doesn't matter: the above declaration is not just invalid, but since it's not at the end of the struct it doesn't even make sense as a language extension.

Instead, use `std::vector`, like this:

```
    std::vector<TMember> m_member_tab;
```

It keeps track of the array size, so you don't need that extra member.

---

In other news, C++ directly supports initialization of an instance of a class. You should not define ordinary function for that. Instead use the language mechanism for that, namely a **constructor**.

You can find information about constructors in any tutorial and any introductory C++ textbook.

The language supported mechanism has many advantages compared to an `init` function.

---

Oh, and seeing as each item in the array will contain a key and a value, do consider a `std::map`, or, if you can use C++11 and not just C++98/C03, `std::unordered_map` (faster but no sorted traversal of keys).

Answer (score 1):

in the first line of void TArrayTest::Init():

```
TMember m_member_tab[] =
{
    { 1, 100 },
    { 2, 200 },
    { 3, 300 },
    { 4, 400 },
    { 5, 500 },
};
```

you declare "m_member_tab" a temporary variable, not Member variable. you should  write like this:
    m_member_tab[] =
    {
        { 1, 100 },
        { 2, 200 },
        { 3, 300 },
        { 4, 400 },
        { 5, 500 },
    };

Comment: That alone doesn't help. But anyway +1 for pointing out my mistake of using reckless usage of temp var.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are trying to use does not exist in C++ language. It is illegal to use `[]` in non-static member array declarations. It is allowed in static member array declarations, but non in non-static ones.

Even if your compiler somehow allows this declaration, it probably interprets it as a zero-sized array. The array size is fixed at that point - there's no way to somehow "intialize" it into a bigger array later.

Member array declaration with `[]` might be allowed by some compilers as a way to support C-style ["struct hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542/c-struct-hack-at-work). But that is a completely different technique.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the only way (if I need to stick to C++98) is to declare a _public_ array of struct. Then in the implementation file (outside the class itself), I can initialize the array without knowing the number of items (following C99 syntax).

That works, but what I don't really like is the fact the array itself (and the struct type) must be _public_.

There is a suggestion above to use _vector_. But I haven't found a way to initialize vector of structs the way I did with C99 array (i.e., without knowing the number of elements).

Comment: @artm: Um... I don't see how making the array public can make any difference here. As I said above, as long as your array remains a non-static member of the class, it is not possible to "redefine" the number of elements.