# Looping thru member array gives wrong values

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, member

I've set up two classes, `Dog` and `AnotherDog`. `Dog` is not meant to be a base class for `AnotherDog`.

In `AnotherDog`, I have a `Dog` object. Within that `Dog` object is a member array. When an `AnotherDog` object call its `Dog` member, then has the member loop thru its member array, I get the wrong results.

```
#include <iostream>

class Dog
{
private:
    int m_NumberOfBarks;
    int m_Decibels[];
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog();

    void setBarkDecibels(int decibel1, int decibel2);
    void loopDecibels();
};

Dog::Dog() : m_NumberOfBarks(2){}
Dog::~Dog(){}

void Dog::setBarkDecibels(int decibel1, int decibel2){
    m_Decibels[0]=  decibel1;
    m_Decibels[1]=  decibel2;
}

void Dog::loopDecibels(){
    for(int i=0; i<m_NumberOfBarks; ++i){
        std::cout << i << ' ' << m_Decibels[i] << std::endl;
    }
}


class AnotherDog
{
private:
    Dog m_Dog;
public:
    AnotherDog();
    ~AnotherDog();

    Dog getDog();
};

AnotherDog::AnotherDog(){
    m_Dog.setBarkDecibels(10, 100);
}
AnotherDog::~AnotherDog(){}

Dog AnotherDog::getDog(){
    return m_Dog;
}


int main(){
    AnotherDog goodDog;
    goodDog.getDog().loopDecibels();
    return 0;
}
```

I want `void Dog::loopDecibels()` to print `10` and `100`, along with the index.

Instead I get this:

```
0 0
1 4196480
```

What am I doing wrong?

How do I achieve the result I want?

Comment: `int m_Decibels[];` is not valid. You need to specify a size for the array (or better yet, use a `std::vector`).

Comment: use std::vector<int> instead in int[]

Comment: @crashmstr, it is somewhat valid. There is an old arcane rule allowing to have your last member of the struct defined in this manner - and than it can be used as a pointer to memory beyond the struct - and some compilers still allow it.

Comment: Unrelated: Why not have 1 dog class, create 2 different dogs, and either give dogs a method to interact with each other or have the object that owns both dogs somehow negotiate interactions between them?

Comment: @SergeyA  This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542/c-struct-hack-at-work

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program exhibits undefined behaviour.

```
 int m_Decibels[];
```

Declares a **pointer** to int, and does not allocate any memory for the pointer to point to. Pointer remains uninitialized in the class constructor (since you do not initialize it). When later you do

```
m_Decibels[0]=  decibel1;
m_Decibels[1]=  decibel2;
```

You are **dereferencing** this pointer, which is a no-no. To fix this, you can use a fixed-size array:

```
int m_Decibels[2];
```

The other side of the coin is that you are returning an instance of `Dog` from your `getDog` by value. When you are setting your decibels on this particular instance, it has no effect on the original `dog` member of the class. To fix this, you might want to return your object by a reference, like this:

```
   Dog& getDog(); // and corresponding change in the definition
```

Comment: I've added a size to the array as @crashmstr recommended. Can you tell me what you mean by "When you are setting your decibels on this particular instance, it has no effect on the original dog member of the class"? Are you talking about `m_dog`?

Comment: @Username, when you return your `dog` by value, you are returning a copy. Modifications to the copy do not affect original.

Comment: Then I should return by address if I want to modify 'm_dog' when called by 'getDog()'? 'return &m_dog'?

Comment: @Username, better return by reference. Makes it much clearer.

Comment: Ok, if you add that to your answer, with the suggestion to assign a size to the array, I can mark your answer the correct one.