# Memory allocation in structs

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

[image]

How can there be idCount of idEntries if idEntries is an array of only 1 element?
Wouldn't this only be true if it was so: `idEntries[idCount]`?

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: This is an instance of the 'Struct Hack' at work (see [C struct hack at work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542/c-struct-hack-at-work) for one of no doubt many possible references). It isn't good practice in Modern C — the flexible array member (FAM) was added to C99 to support it directly in the language.  Technically, C++ doesn't support the FAM concept. I'm not sure it supports the struct hack either.  Code using the technique is usually treading on thin ice, therefore.  No, you can't have a variable size array in a structure, so the `idEntries[idCount]` notation is a non-starter.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So is it a bad practice?I haven't seen this kind of hack anywhere else.

Comment: One problem in C++ is that you cannot use the `new` mechanisms to allocate the structure — you're forced to use `malloc()` and friends to do the memory allocation.  The intent is that you allocate `sizeof(ICONDIR) + idCount * sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY)` bytes in total, and treat the first `sizeof(ICONDIR)` bytes as the `ICONDIR` structure, and the array happens to extend into the extra space added.  That's not good C++ style, needless to say.

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice.  You may be forced to use it because of compatibility reasons, but you should not code like that yourself.  It could be a `vector<ICONDIRENTRY> idEntries`, for example, and then you don't need the separate count.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed, it might be a bad practice in general. But it is hard to avoid if you do some Win API stuff. (And MS allows [unsized arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fae073.aspx).).

Comment: @AlexD: Interesting — what Microsoft refers to as an 'unsized array' is what the C99 and C11 standards refer to as a 'flexible array member' or FAM.  And I noted that 'compatibility reasons' might be why you need to use it — compatibility with Win API calls may be a reason to use it.  It doesn't alter the observation that you should not design your code using that technique unless external constraints demand it.  (I note that G++ does allow FAMs; the C++ standard does not.)

Comment: @TrevorHickey https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why can't I use `new` to allocate structure? I have seen people using it, I have been using it and it works.

Comment: @Brackets I assume because you cant allocate the extra memory for the buffer with new.

Comment: So how many `idEntries` are there created? Does it become like `vector`'s `push_back` every time I write to next array's element?

Comment: FAM breaks the contract  laid out by the `struct` by taking advantage of the extra space asked for when the structure was `malloc`ed. Unless you go with placement `new` into a presized allocation, `new` will build a `ICONDIR` with exactly one `ICONDIRENTRY` as per the contract.

Comment: @Brackets There are no `push_back`s, memory gets allocated just once. The point is to have a continuous chunk: "the header" and then the array.

Comment: Is it how many additional `sizeof(ICONDIRENTRY)`s I allocate with `malloc`?

Comment: That's a yes.21