# Why is a False value (0) smaller in bytes than True (1)?

Tags: python, types, size, cpython

I was playing around with `sys`'s `getsizeof()` and found that `False` (or `0`) consists of less bytes than `True` (or `1`). Why is that?

```
import sys

print("Zero: " + str(sys.getsizeof(0)))
print("One: " + str(sys.getsizeof(1)))
print("False: " + str(sys.getsizeof(False)))
print("True: " + str(sys.getsizeof(True)))

# Prints:
# Zero: 24
# One: 28
# False: 24
# True: 28
```

In fact, other numbers (also some that consist of more than one digit) are 28 bytes.

```
for n in range(0, 12):
  print(str(n) + ": " + str(sys.getsizeof(n)))

# Prints:
# 0: 24
# 1: 28
# 2: 28
# 3: 28
# 4: 28
# 5: 28
# 6: 28
# 7: 28
# 8: 28
# 9: 28
# 10: 28
# 11: 28
```

Even more: `sys.getsizeof(999999999)` is also 28 bytes! `sys.getsizeof(9999999999)`, however, is 32.

So what's going on? I assume that the booleans `True` and `False` are internally converted to `0` and `1` respectively, but why is zero different in size from other lower integers?

Side question: is this specific to how Python (3) represents these items, or is this generally how digits are presented in the OS?

Comment: On python2.7, I get "24" for all of these. I reproduced your results on 3.6. This appears to be python3 specific.

Comment: It's very Python-specific. Most programming languages don't have arbitrary-precision integers, you have to choose data types like `int`, `long`, `long long`, etc. and they each have fixed size.

Comment: @jordanm It's not quite Python 3 specific—you see the same thing in Python 2 if you compare `0L`, `1L`, etc. The difference is that Python 2 had separate types for `int` (fixed-size 32-bit signed integer) and `long` (arbitrary-sized integer), while Python 3 renamed `long` to `int` and got rid of `int`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remember that Python `int` values are of arbitrary size. How does that work?

Well, in CPython,<sup>1</sup> an int is represented by a `PyLong_Object`, which has an array of 4-byte chunks<sup>2</sup>, each holding 30 bits<sup>3</sup> worth of the number.

- `0` takes no chunks at all.
- `1` - `(1<<30)-1` takes 1 chunk.
- `1<<30` - `(1<<60)-1` takes 2 chunks.

And so on.

This is slightly oversimplified; for full details, see [`longintrepr.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longintrepr.h) in the source.

---

In Python 2, there are two separate types, called `int` and `long`. An `int` is represented by a C 32-bit signed integer<sup>4</sup> embedded directly in the header, instead of an array of chunks. A `long` is like a Python 3 `int`.

If you do the same test with `0L`, `1L`, etc., to explicitly ask for `long` values, you will get the same results as in Python 3. But without the `L` suffix, any literal that fits in 32 bits gives you an `int`, and only literals that are too big give you `long`s.<sup>5</sup> (This means that `(1<<31)-1` is an `int`, but `1<<31` is a 2-chunk `long`.)

---

<sub>1. In a different implementation, this might not be true. IIRC, Jython does roughly the same thing as CPython, but IronPython uses a C# "bignum" implementation.</sub>

<sub>2. Why 30 bits instead of 32? Mainly because the implementation of `pow` and `**` can be simpler and faster if it can assume that the number of bits in two "digits" is divisible by `10`.</sub>

<sub>3. It uses the C ["struct hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542). Technically, a `Py_LongObject` is 28 bytes, but nobody ever allocates a `Py_LongObject`; they malloc 24, 28, 32, 36, etc. bytes then cast to `Py_LongObject *`.</sub>

<sub>4. In fact, a Python `int` is a C `long`, just to make things confusing. So the C API is full of things like `PyInt_FromLong` where the `long` means "32-bit int" and `PyLong_FromSize_t` where the `long` means "bignum".</sub>

<sub>5. Early versions of Python 2.x didn't integrate `int` and `long` as nicely, but hopefully nobody has to worry about those anymore.</sub>

Comment: In very layman terms, would it make sense to say that the empty `PyLong_Object` takes 24 bytes. A `PyLong_Object` with an empty array is the same as zero. As soon as you actually have an int > 0 the object's array isn't empty anymore, therefore its array of 4-byte chunks gets filled, explaining the increase in size?

Comment: @BramVanroy Yes, that's right (to understand it any deeper, you need to know about the C ["struct hack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553542)).