# Why does gcc say this is an "invalid initializer"?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
    int blah;
    int bleh;
} Foo;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Foo* arr[];
} Bar;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Bar* bar = malloc(sizeof(Bar) + sizeof(Foo) * 5);
    Foo foo1 = bar->arr[0];
    return 0;
}
```

On the line where `foo1` is assigned, I get "invalid initializer". If I change the type to `Foo*`, it compiles. But then if I do `foo1->blah = 3`, the program crashes.

Why is the type of array elements `Foo*` and not `Foo`? And why is the program crashing?

Comment: 'Why is the type of array elements Foo*' -- because, of course, you declared them to be with `Foo* arr[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` is an array of `Foo*` so you can not assign an element of `arr` to a `Foo` here:

```
 Foo foo1 = bar->arr[0];
```

the second issue is even if you were allocating memory for `arr` properly you need to initialize each `pointer` as well, otherwise you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer which is undefined behavior.

If you want an array of `Foo` then this is what you want:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    Foo arr[];
} Bar;
```

then the rest of your code does not change.

This is using [flexible array members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad) introduced in `C99` and the answers here talk about how to allocate and free properly.

Answer (score 2):

The type of array elements is `Foo *` because this is exactly how you declared them. The declaration `Foo* arr[]` stands for an array of `Foo *` elements. Why did you expect the elements to be `Foo`, when you explicitly said `Foo *` in the declaration?

Changing the type of `foo1` to `Foo *` looks like a random change that does not make much sense. What are you trying to do - this is the question you should answer first. What kind of array do you need at the end of `Bar`? `Foo arr[]` or `Foo *arr[]`?

Judging by your `malloc` it appears that you want to declare an array of `Foo` elements at the end of `Bar`. If so, you have to change the array declaration to `Foo arr[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo* arr[]` is an array of pointers, so `bar->arr[0]` is a pointer.

This works fine:

```
Foo* foo1 = bar->arr[0];
```

To create an object of `Foo` you can use either one of the following

```
Foo bar1 = *bar->arr[0] // or **bar->arr; though this may be less clear
```