# C Struct array member without specific length

Tags: c, gcc

I have encountered this piece of code:

```
struct test                   
{                                        
 uint32       num_fields;            
 char array_field [];               
};
```

How can I understand `array_field`? Is this a gcc extension for the C language?

Comment: Please revert the update and post a new question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a C99 feature, called *flexible array member* which is typically used to create a variable length array.

It can only be specified as the last member of a *struct* without specifying the size (as in `array_field [];`).

---

For example, you can do the following and the member `arr` will have 5 bytes allocated for it:

```
struct flexi_example
{
int data;
char arr[];
};


struct flexi_example *obj;

obj = malloc(sizeof (struct flexi_example) + 5);
```

Its pros/cons discussed here:

**[Flexible array members in C - bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246977/flexible-array-members-in-c-bad)**

Comment: Any idea why this was added to C instead of just using pointers?  I hardly see why to use arrays at all except to allocate some pre-determined space on the stack.  This doesn't give you that benefit.

Comment: I finally got the point when I printf the sizeof of the struct. Actually, the array_field does not occupy any bytes, it's the same thing as array_field[0], which is used to create a variable length array in gcc.

Comment: @undur_gongor sorry for the delay. I was commuting ;).

Comment: @xaxxon It's not an irreplaceable feature. I believe it was added based on the GNU extension zero length member. Details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: @xaxxon It's added because with this feature, you can have true VLAs *inside* a struct, and you don't have to mallocate memory *twice.* This increases readability and decreases memory fragmentation and the number of pointer traversals (and thus perhaps boosts performance a little bit).

Comment: @H2CO3: Flexible array members are not VLAs. In particular, `sizeof` applied to the struct doesn't include the size of the array member; you just have to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes I know that, still the reasoning is correct I believe.

Comment: @H2CO3: VLAs and flexible array members have similarities, but they're distinct features. I suggest that referring to flexible array members as VLAs is likely to cause confusion.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, you're correct with regards to wording, sorry about that. Under "reasoning" I meant the response I gave to xaxxon.

Comment: The flexible array member was added to formalize the [long existing and relied upon "struct hack"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2b[c]%20%22struct%20hack%22) (that search really isn't complete, as some instances are left off, but without the quotes a lot of junk creeps in).

Answer (score 3):

Such structures are usually allocated on the heap with a calculated size, with code such as the following:

```c
#include <stddef.h>

struct test * test_new(uint32 num_fields)
{
    size_t sizeBeforeArray = offsetof(struct test, array_field);
    size_t sizeOfArray = num_fields * sizeof(char);
    struct test * ret = malloc(sizeBeforeArray + sizeOfArray);
    if(NULL != ret)
    {
        ret->num_fields = num_fields;
    }
    return ret;
}
```