# Implementing stacks in C, using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct, stack, malloc

I am trying to implement a Stack in C using arrays just for the sake of learning.

I am making some decisions in how this is implemented (suggestions are welcome), basically I proposed a struct for the stack containing the array and an index 't' of the top element.
Then I have a function to create the stack which allocates the memory depending on the size defined by the user, this is how it looks so far:

**UPDATE**: I have used some of your suggestions and this is how version 2.0 looks like until now. I also created an online document with version 1.0 for anybody interested ([here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19b3-QoQYhZfQbKMnY2A2KqEtXtKxi30uo_Dt-i9xsgI/edit?usp=sharing))

**stack.h**

```
// Interface for a stack data structure using arrays

typedef struct Stack{
    int t;          // Index of the top element in st
    int maxSize;    // Max size, allows to be resized when full
    int* st;        // Changed from int[] to int*
}Stack;

void initStack(Stack* s, int length);   // Declare the initial length
void push(Stack* s, int elem);
int pop(Stack* s);
int top(Stack* s);
int size_s(Stack* s);
int isEmpty(Stack* s);
void print(Stack* s);                   // Visualize the stack
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"
#include <malloc.h>


void initStack(Stack* s, int length){
    s->st = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    s->maxSize = length;    // Initial size (this could also have a default number since it would be able to grow)
    s->t = -1;              // Initialize the size (index) to -1 to indicate an empty stack
}

void push(Stack* s, int elem){
    int* tmp;
    int i;
    if(size_s(s) == s->maxSize){  // Resize to double the size if full...
        // WOULD IT BE POSSIBLE TO REPLACE ALL OF THIS USING REALLOC() ?
        s->maxSize = s->maxSize * 2;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(int)*s->maxSize);
        for(i = 0; i < size_s(s); i++){
            tmp[i] = s->st[i];
        }
        free(s->st);
        s->st = tmp;
    }

    int t = s->t + 1;
    s->t = t;
    s->st[t] = elem;
}

int top(Stack* s){
    if(isEmpty(s)) return -1;   // Empty stack
    return s->st[s->t];
}

int pop(Stack* s){
    int element;
    if(isEmpty(s)) return -1;    // Empty stack
    element = s->st[s->t];

    //////////////////////////////////////
    s->st[s->t] = 0;            // Empty the previous location, what other value could I use?
                                // Would it make sense to use free() ? I would need to malloc() again right?
    //////////////////////////////////////

    s->t = s->t - 1;
    return element;
}

int size_s(Stack* s){
    return (s->t) + 1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* s){
    if(s->t == -1){
        return 1;   // True
    }else{
        return 0;   // False
    }
}

void print(Stack* s){
    int len = size_s(s);
    printf("Length: %d\n",len);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%d ",s->st[i]);
    }
}
```

<s>I haven't tested all the functions yet but that is a basic structure on how I would implement them.</s>

OBS: The push operation is still not safe because I'm not checking whether or not the stack is full.

The test code I am running is

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
    Stack* s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    int i = 0;
    initStack(s,10);    // Declare an initial size

    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        push(s,i);
        printf("Size of stack: %d, MaxSize: %d\n",size_s(s),s->maxSize);
    }
    printf("Top element: %d\n",top(s));
    print(s);
    puts("");
    popped = pop(s);
    printf("Popped: %d\n",popped);
    print(s);
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Size of stack: 1, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 2, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 3, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 4, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 5, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 6, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 7, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 8, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 9, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 10, MaxSize: 10
Size of stack: 11, MaxSize: 20
Size of stack: 12, MaxSize: 20
Top element: 11
Length: 12
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
Popped: 11
Length: 11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

<s>There is a bug in the program, I am only testing 3 functions:</s>

- newStack
- push
- print

The program has no compilation or explicit runtime error, it will only crash and I can't figure out why.
I am not entirely sure about the newStack() method because I am allocating memory in an odd way that I found about ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185247/c-struct-array-member-without-specific-length?lq=1)) so that the typedef of the Stack struct has an array of an unknown size.

In some other tests I did sometimes I get some garbage values in some of the cells of the array.

Thanks, I'll keep posting all the fixes and updates to this implementation.

I would also love to hear your suggestions on the implementation i.e. header file etc.

Comment: Don't forget to free  your memory. Also, you probably should consider keeping the size, rather than the index of the top, and instead use a function to get the top. Then your size is 0 if there are no elements.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: Technically true, but that really isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Unless you're storing a `char`type (and you're not), the allocated size won't be correct. At least that's what I see off the top.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not entirely sure why is that, could you explain further? I am guessing that I would need to multiply the lenght * sizeof(int) to get the size correct?

Comment: @OmarMuñoz that would be a good guess.

Comment: use allways ptrdiff_t or size_t for sizes and for array index, not int.

Comment: In my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073100/array-of-struct-pointers-c-programming-issues/36073580#36073580 see the `set_append` function [which is equivalent to your `push`] for the way to use `realloc`

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack* s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack)+length);
```

Should be:

```
Stack* s = malloc(sizeof(Stack)+length*sizeof(int));
```

Also, you should save length in the struct to use for overflow checking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to free  your memory. Also, you probably should consider keeping the size, rather than the index of the top, and instead use a function to get the top. Then your size is 0 if there are no elements. Finally your data member should be an `int *` rather than a `int[]` because a pointer better implies a realizable array.

The function `newStack` could be better by instead calling it `initStack` and passing it a `Stack *`, just like the rest of the functions.

```
void initStack(Stack* s, int length){
    s.size = 0;
     s.maxSize = length;
    s.data = malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: There's a reason for that  `int[]` decl, and that reason is in the comment immediately following its declaration.

Comment: Also, I'd return a `Stack` rather than a `Stack *` because your actual data is already a pointer-type.

Comment: Yes, I'll keep in mind to use free on the pop operation. But why would a pointer be better? I did consider both but I couldn't figure out what would be the best and why

Comment: @RussleyShaw Yes I guess that is a better design decision, I would return the Stack instead, great help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @RussleyShaw But I am guessing that by returning the stack itself, I would need to create a local variable to store it and that makes me wonder about the memory allocation (I'm kind of new here), I think that the local variable itself would be stored in the program stack and not in the heap right? it seems contradictory to me because I would have already allocated memory for it.

Comment: Oh I see you also suggested to avoid returning it and instead initialize it, that is also a good option. It kind of reminds me to object oriented programming where you have the "this" pointer.

Comment: Thats essentially what you were replicating anyways with the other functions, at least this way, its consistent.