# Why is int a[0] allowed in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I find that in the declaration of an array, we cannot specify the size of it like this

```
int a[0];
```

I know, empty size array illegal in C++, but In my code, empty size array compiler allowed and give the output.

My code is here :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int a[0];

        a[0] = 10;
        a[1] = 20;

        cout<<a[0]<<endl;
        cout<<a[1]<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
20
```

Online compiler link : http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/TteOmO

So, My question is, Why is `int a[0]` allowed GCC compiler?

Comment: Doing `int a[0];       a[0] = 10;        a[1] = 20;`  will lead to FireWorks(UB).

Comment: OP knows it is wrong, question is why does the compiler not raise an error. Answer to which, I suppose, would be that it cannot do everything for you ;)

Comment: `error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'a' [-Wpedantic]int a[0];`

Comment: Most likely because adding a special rule disallowing it would be too much added parser complexity for very little gain.

Comment: It's allowed because it's a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).

Answer (score 5):

It issues a warning, for example clang outputs:

```
warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-Wzero-length-array]
```

this is undefined behaviour:

```
    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = 20;
```

Zero length arrays are extensions for gcc, why - you can read on it here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

> They are very useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object:

This is actually C extension but it looks like it also is used in C++, probably to make it easier to use existing structures from C that uses this extension.

Comment: Also comment that the more portable solution for this type of structures is an array without size, like `a[]`. This is added in C99: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17185530/3742943

Answer (score 0):

Please Look Into This

[What happens if I define a 0-size array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)
If It's a good compiler it will catch that and give a warning.
but with pedantic option compiler can catch it.