# Unsized array declaration in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, flexible-array-member

Why does *C* permit this:

```
typedef struct s
{
  int arr[];
} s;
```

where the array `arr` has no size specified?

Comment: Standard C does not permit the structure shown. There must be at least one named member in the structure as well as the flexible array member or FAM (and the FAM must be last).  A minimal structure might be `typedef struct s { int size; int arr[]; } s;` which allows you to record the size of the array (in the `size` member).  That size is almost certainly necessary to be able to access the array member reliably.

Comment: _Try working in a language like (UCSD) Pascal that does not allow flexible arrays and you will appreciate this feature._

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is C99 feature called *flexible arrays*, the main feature is to allow the [use variable length array like features inside a struct](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c/184401497?pgno=2) and *R..* in this [answer to another question on flexible array members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001919/1708801) provides a list of benefits to using *flexible arrays* over *pointers*. The [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `6.7.2.1` *Structure and union specifiers* paragraph *16* says:

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply. [...]

So if you had a `s*` you would allocate space for the array in addition to space required for the *struct*, usually you would have other members in the structure:

```
s *s1 = malloc( sizeof(struct s) + n*sizeof(int) ) ;
```

the draft standard actually has a instructive example in paragraph *17*:

> EXAMPLE After the declaration:
>
> ```
>   struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure struct `s` has a flexible array member `d`. A typical way to use this
>       is:
>
> ```
>    int m = /* some value */;
>    struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to by `p`
>       behaves, for most purposes, as if `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
>     struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```
>
> (there are circumstances in which this equivalence is broken; in particular, the
>        offsets of member `d` might not be the same).

Comment: it compiles with gcc -std=c89

Comment: @sashang `gcc` may allow it as an extension outside of C99 like it does other featrues such as VLA, if you use `-pedantic` it should provide a warning if this is the case. Just tried `gcc` warns *warning: ISO C90 does not support flexible array members [-pedantic]*.

Comment: @sashang Odd as it may seem, the compiler option `-std=` does not enforce standard compliance. In order to compile according to a given standard you must use `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors`. Which will correctly give "error: ISO C90 does not support flexible array members"

Comment: OP's example is actually incorrect. The struct must have at least two members, of which one may be the flexible array member.

Comment: @2501 yeah, I guess this is a GNU extension to flexible array members, hmmm.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for flexible arrays in C99. **Flexible array members** are members of unknown size at the end of a struct/union.

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member
>   is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more
>   trailing padding than the omission would imply.

You may also look at the [reason for the **struct hack**](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) in the first place.

> It's not clear if it's legal or portable, but it is rather popular. An implementation of the technique might look something like this:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    struct name *makename(char *newname)
    {
        struct name *ret =
            malloc(sizeof(struct name)-1 + strlen(newname)+1);
                    /* -1 for initial [1]; +1 for \0 */
        if(ret != NULL) {
            ret->namelen = strlen(newname);
            strcpy(ret->namestr, newname);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

> This function allocates an instance of the name structure with the
>   size adjusted so that the namestr field can hold the requested name
>   (not just one character, as the structure declaration would suggest).
>
> Despite its popularity, the technique is also somewhat notorious -
>   *Dennis Ritchie has called it "unwarranted chumminess with the C implementation."* An official interpretation has deemed that it is NOT
>   strictly conforming with the C Standard, although it does seem to work
>   under all known implementations. Compilers that check array bounds
>   carefully might issue warnings.

Comment: I'm curious what Dennis Ritchie would advocate instead of the struct hack?  IMHO, the best alternative would have been to have compilers not squawk at zero-size array declarations, in which case compilers could have safely assumed that if an array in a struct has a declared size of `N`, no attempt would be made to access any element beyond `N-1u` or the last one for which space is occupied, whichever is lower.

Comment: OP's example is actually incorrect. The struct must have at least two members, of which one may be the flexible array member.