# How to allocate memory with different type in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have the following code in C:

```
typedef struct
{
   int age;
   int phoneNumber;
} Student;

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  int student[1];
} People;

#define NUM_OF_PEOPLE
void *p = malloc(sizeof(People) + sizeof(int) * NUM_OF_PEOPLE + sizeof(Student) * NUM_OF_PEOPLE);
```

How could I find the pointer to the memory point to the first element of `struct Student` in the memory?

I try to do it in the following way:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PEOPLE; i++)
{
   Student * student_p = p.student[NUM_OF_PEOPLE];
}
```

It does not work, so can we allocate memory in the way?
And how to find the first element of `struct Student` in the memory?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221012/unsized-array-declaration-in-a-struct/20221073#20221073) of mine has a good example of using flexible array members.

Comment: Why not have an array of `Student` in `People`?

Comment: well, the struct can not be changed

Comment: It seems like you are trying to create an array of pointers in the `People` struct where each pointer points to a `Student` struct.  But in that case the `int student[1]` member should be declared as `Student *student[]`;

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an ancient way of having a flexible array member, which was technically also undefined behavior.

You are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14643406/912144).

First, you need to define your struct like this (I don't know what the `ints` before the `Students` are, so let's just call it id):

```
typedef struct
{
   int age;
   int phoneNumber;
} Student;

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  Student student;
} StudentAndId;

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  StudentAndId students[];
} People;
```

Note the lack of size in the array inside `People`. Now you do this:

```
People *p = malloc(sizeof(People) + sizeof(StudentAndId[NUM_OF_PEOPLE]));
```

Then you can access `students` inside `p` *as if* it was an array of `NUM_OF_PEOPLE` elements.

---

Remember to compile with C99 (or C11) support. With gcc that would be `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99`.

Comment: does not understand, do you mean this does not work?

Comment: @ratzip, it might, but the correct syntax is a bit different. I'll write an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

This will allocate memory for storing the date but how you access it depends on how you store date. using C pointers you can store and access data using this structure and allocation but accessing the members will not be direct. it will involve pointer arithmetic. So better to use other structure if possible. If using this way of allocation then you need to do pointer arithmetic to get the next elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   int age;
   int phoneNumber;
} Student;

typedef struct
{
  int id;
  int student[1];
} People;

#define NUM_OF_PEOPLE 10
int main()
{
   People *p = malloc(sizeof(People) + sizeof(int) * NUM_OF_PEOPLE + sizeof(Student) * NUM_OF_PEOPLE);
   int* id = (int*)(p+1);
   Student* s = (Student*)(id+NUM_OF_PEOPLE);

   printf("Size of People : %d\n", sizeof(People));
   printf("p points to    : %p\n", p);
   printf("id points to   : %p\n", id);
   printf("s points to    : %p\n", s);
}
```

Here's a sample output:

```
Size of People : 8
p points to    : 0x80010460
id points to   : 0x80010468
s points to    : 0x80010490
```

Comment: Note that this is generally not a good idea. For example, if `Student` starts with a `uint64_t` variable and `sizeof(People) + sizeof(int) * NUM_OF_PEOPLE` is not a multiple of 8, then you would end up having mis-aligned 64-bit variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the `id` field to your `Student` data structure, e.g.:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int age;
    int phoneNumber;
} Student;
```

Then, you can define a structure having a fixed header (in this case, this can be the number of students), followed by a variable-sized array of `Student`s:

```
#define ARRAY_OF_ANY_SIZE   1

typedef struct {
    int count;
    Student students[ARRAY_OF_ANY_SIZE];
} People;
```

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx) explains this technique of having *"arrays of size 1"*, including a discussion of the *alignment* problem.

I won't repeat the original blog post code here. Just consider that you can use the portable [`offsetof()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) instead of the Windows-specific `FIELD_OFFSET()` macro.

As a sample code, you may want to consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* For printf()                  */
#include <stddef.h>    /* For offsetof()                */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* For dynamic memory allocation */

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int age;
    int phoneNumber;
} Student;

#define ARRAY_OF_ANY_SIZE   1

typedef struct {
    int count;
    Student students[ARRAY_OF_ANY_SIZE];
} People;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    People* people;
    const int numberOfStudents = 3;
    int i;
    
    /* Dynamically allocate memory to store the data structure */
    people = malloc(offsetof(People, students[numberOfStudents]));
    /* Check memory allocation ... */
    
    /* Fill the data structure */
    people->count = numberOfStudents;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        people->students[i].id = i;
        people->students[i].age = (i+1)*10;
        people->students[i].phoneNumber = 11000 + i;
    }  
    
    /* Print the data structure content */
    for (i = 0; i < people->count; i++) {
        printf("id: %d, age=%d, phone=%d\n",
               people->students[i].id,
               people->students[i].age,
               people->students[i].phoneNumber);
    }
    
    /* Release the memory allocated by the data structure */
    free(people);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> id: 0, age=10, phone=11000
> id: 1, age=20, phone=11001
> id: 2, age=30, phone=11002
> ```

Comment: Yes, but how to allocate struct student and a array of int, then access it and fill data?