# Pass struct pointer element to FIFO - C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, fifo

I am developing a client/server application in C, in which multiple clients send requests through a common FIFO.

The data being sent to the server is a struct containing multiple parameters including a pointer to an array of ints (pref_seat_list).

```
struct request {
  pid_t pid;
  int num_wanted_seats;
  int *pref_seat_list; // <-- where the issue lies
  int pref_seats_size;
};
```

The client sends the data through the FIFO but, **on the server's end, the pointer *points* to a random/invalid address** (understandable).

I could fix the issue by making pref_seat_list a fixed size array

```
int pref_seat_list[size]
```

, but it must behave as a dynamic size array that is initialized and allocated on the client side.

Is there a workaround for the pointer to somehow go through the FIFO without having to make its size fixed?

------------------------------------------------- FIX 1 -------------------------------------------------------

- Include FAM concept

The struct now looks like this

```
struct request {
  pid_t pid;
  int num_wanted_seats;
  int pref_seats_size;
  int pref_seat_list[];
};
```

The initialization of the struct has been done:
// Getting the size of pref_seat_list so we can initialize and allocate the array

```
  // CLIENT.C
  int pref_seats_size = count_seats_list(arglist[3]);

  // Allocating space for request struct's pref_seat_list array (flexible array member)
  struct request *req = malloc(sizeof(struct request) + sizeof(int[pref_seats_size]));
  if (req == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal: failed to allocate memory for the struct request");
    exit(0);
  }
```

Filling the struct's fields

```
  // CLIENT.C
  // Getting client's PID
  req->pid = getpid();

  // Getting client's number of wanted seats
  char *end;
  req->num_wanted_seats = strtol(arglist[2], &end, 10);

  // Assigning size of the struct's pref_seat_list array
  req->pref_seats_size = pref_seats_size;

  // Assigning list of seats to struct's pref_seat_list dynamic array
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(arglist[3], " ");
  while (token != NULL)
  {
    req->pref_seat_list[i++] = strtol(token, &end, 10);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
```

Expected output (SERVER.C)

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12
```

Actual output (SERVER.C) - random values

```
3250, 0, 0, 123131, 1, 345691, 1
```

Comment: Can you change the order of the fields in the struct and place `pref_seat_list` last one? If yes, you can define it as `int pref_seat_list[];` (more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221073/5218277 )

Comment: @AlexLop. Yes it can be the last field. But would it only work if it was the last one? I will try the fix you linked. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it **MUST** be the last field in the struct.

Comment: Read about serialization (marshalling) data. When you cross protection domains (or pass data to another host), then you need a 'deep copy' of all referenced data that will be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Outline solution

You'll need to handle the list of preferred seats separately from the main structure.  Using a [flexible array member](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18) (FAM) from C99 and beyond might be the simplest. The FAM must be the last member of the structure.

```
struct request
{
    pid_t pid;
    int num_wanted_seats;
    int pref_seats_size;
    int pref_seat_list[];
};
```

You allocate space for a request with `num_prefs` preferred seats with:

```
struct request *rp = malloc(sizeof(*rp) + num_prefs * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]));
```

Note that `sizeof(struct request)` (aka `sizeof(*rp)`) does not include the size of the array (though it might include some padding that wouldn't be present if the FAM was not present, though that's not a problem here).

After checking that the allocation succeeded, you fill in the structure and array with the information required (copying `num_prefs` into `rp->pref_seats_size`).  You can then write it all at once with:

```
fwrite(rp, sizeof(*rp) + rp->pref_seats_size * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0])), 1, fp);
```

Now, how does the reading code handle this?  It doesn't know how big a space to allocate until it has read the `struct record` main information, so you have to take two bites at the cherry:

```
struct request req_hdr;   // No space for the FAM
struct request *rp;

if (fread(&req_hdr, sizeof(req_hdr), 1, fp) != 1)
    …EOF or other problems…
rp = malloc(sizeof(*rp) + req_hdr->pref_seats_size * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]));
// … error check allocation …
*rp = req_hdr;
if (fread(rp->pref_seat_list, sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]) * rp->pref_seats_size, 1, fp) != 1)
    …Protocol error…
```

The first read gets the fixed-size data, which also tells the receiving process how much variable-length data will follow.  It allocates the correct space, and then reads the variable-length data into the allocated structure.

Note that this does assume that the process on the receiving end has the same size characteristics as the sending process.  Since you're using a FIFO, your I/O is on a single machine, but there could, in theory, be problems with other types if the sending process is 64-bit and the receiving process is 32-bit, or vice versa — except that you're dealing with `int` types (assuming `pid_t` is `int` or `unsigned` in disguise) which will probably be all 32-bit regardless of 32-bit vs 64-bit issues.  With other types or more complex structures, or if you were using a network connection rather than a local connection, you would have to work harder to get the data sent accurately in all circumstances.

---

### POC Code

This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `send29.c`, `recv29.c`, `dumpreq.c` and `request.h` in the [src/so-5030-9324](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-5030-9324) sub-directory.

This code use my standard error reporting functions, which are also available in my SOQ repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

#### `request.h`

```
#ifndef REQUEST_H_INCLUDED
#define REQUEST_H_INCLUDED

#define FIFO_NAME "seat-request.fifo"

struct request
{
    int pid;
    int num_wanted_seats;
    int pref_seats_size;
    int pref_seat_list[];
};

extern void dump_request(const char *tag, const struct request *rp);

#endif /* REQUEST_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### `send29.c`

```
#include "request.h"
#include "stderr.h"     /* See https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>   /* mkfifo() */
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 0)               // Use argc - avoid unused argument warning
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    /* Maybe the other program already created it? */
    if (mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666) != 0 && errno != EEXIST)
        err_syserr("failed to create FIFO %s: ", FIFO_NAME);

    FILE *fp = fopen(FIFO_NAME, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to open FIFO %s for writing: ", FIFO_NAME);

    printf("Send: PID %d at work with FIFO %s open for writing\n", (int)getpid(), FIFO_NAME);

    struct request *rp = 0;
    int num_prefs = 10;
    size_t req_size = sizeof(*rp) + num_prefs * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]);
    rp = malloc(req_size);
    if (rp == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes memory: ", req_size);

    rp->pid = getpid();
    rp->num_wanted_seats = 3;
    rp->pref_seats_size = num_prefs;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_prefs; i++)
        rp->pref_seat_list[i] = 123 + i;

    dump_request("Sender", rp);

    if (fwrite(rp, req_size, 1, fp) != 1)
        err_syserr("failed to write request (%zu bytes) to FIFO %s: ", req_size, FIFO_NAME);

    free(rp);
    fclose(fp);
    unlink(FIFO_NAME);
    printf("Send: PID %d finished writing %zu bytes to FIFO %s\n", (int)getpid(), req_size, FIFO_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `recv29.c`

```
#include "request.h"
#include "stderr.h"     /* See https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>   /* mkfifo() */
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 0)               // Use argc - avoid unused argument warning
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    /* Maybe the other program already created it? */
    if (mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666) != 0 && errno != EEXIST)
        err_syserr("failed to create FIFO %s: ", FIFO_NAME);

    int fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to open FIFO %s for reading: ", FIFO_NAME);

    printf("Recv: PID %d at work with FIFO %s open for reading\n", (int)getpid(), FIFO_NAME);

    struct request req;
    struct request *rp = 0;
    if (read(fd, &req, sizeof(req)) != sizeof(req))
    {
        /* Marginally dubious error reporting; if the return value is
        ** positive but small, errno has no useful information in it.
        */
        err_syserr("failed to read %zu bytes for head from FIFO %s: ", sizeof(req), FIFO_NAME);
    }
    size_t req_size = sizeof(*rp) + req.pref_seats_size * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]);
    rp = malloc(req_size);
    if (rp == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes memory: ", req_size);

    *rp = req;

    int nbytes = rp->pref_seats_size * sizeof(rp->pref_seat_list[0]);
    //if (read(fd, &rp->pref_seat_list[0], nbytes) != nbytes)
    if (read(fd, rp->pref_seat_list, nbytes) != nbytes)
        err_syserr("failed to read %d bytes for body from FIFO %s: ", nbytes, FIFO_NAME);

    dump_request("Receiver", rp);

    free(rp);
    close(fd);
    unlink(FIFO_NAME);
    printf("Recv: PID %d finished reading request from FIFO %s\n", (int)getpid(), FIFO_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

#### `dumpreq.c`

```
#include "request.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void dump_request(const char *tag, const struct request *rp)
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    printf("- PID requesting seats: %d\n", rp->pid);
    printf("- Number of seats wanted: %d\n", rp->num_wanted_seats);
    printf("- Number of seats in preferred list: %d\n", rp->pref_seats_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < rp->pref_seats_size; i++)
        printf("  %d is seat %d\n", i, rp->pref_seat_list[i]);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

#### Sample run

```
$ send29 & recv29
[1] 55896
Send: PID 55896 at work with FIFO seat-request.fifo open for writing
Sender:
- PID requesting seats: 55896
- Number of seats wanted: 3
- Number of seats in preferred list: 10
  0 is seat 123
  1 is seat 124
  2 is seat 125
  3 is seat 126
  4 is seat 127
  5 is seat 128
  6 is seat 129
  7 is seat 130
  8 is seat 131
Recv: PID 55897 at work with FIFO seat-request.fifo open for reading
  9 is seat 132
Receiver:
- PID requesting seats: 55896
- Number of seats wanted: 3
- Number of seats in preferred list: 10
  0 is seat 123
  1 is seat 124
  2 is seat 125
  3 is seat 126
  4 is seat 127
  5 is seat 128
  6 is seat 129
  7 is seat 130
  8 is seat 131
  9 is seat 132
Send: PID 55896 finished writing 52 bytes to FIFO seat-request.fifo
Recv: PID 55897 finished reading request from FIFO seat-request.fifo
[1]+  Done                    send29
$
```

You can run the programs in either order (so `recv29 & send29` also works).

Comment: I followed the link posted by @AlexLop. and fixed the code accordingly. But on the server's end, instead of getting a segfault (before the FAM implementation), I just get random values this time. I did the assignment to the array "manually" (eg. req->pref_seat_list[0] = 1)

Comment: I've added some outline code for the reading process.  It has to be done in two steps, once to find out how much data to read and then to read it.  In principle, you could try a raw data read for however much data is in the FIFO and see whether that works, but it isn't reliable if the list can be long enough to overfill the FIFO internal buffers.  That probably isn't an issue with this seating application (few people are going to type more than a thousand preferred seats, and that would still leave room to spare), but beware machines sending requests — they might fill in 1000+ preferred seats!

Comment: So this means that the server will have to allocate the intended memory before accessing the array?

Comment: You can't access the memory before allocating it, can you?  Yes, the server must allocate memory before reading.  You may be able to stipulate an upper-bound to how many entries are allowed, and then you might do a conservative allocation of the maximum, and then see how much data is present.  However, that assumes that there is a half-duplex communication protocol with only one sender process, so that there is never any interference caused by reading more data than belongs to the first message in the FIFO.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Writes are atomic as long as they're smaller than the FIFO buffer size, so the write operations won't be interleaved in the FIFO at reasonable sizes of the structure.  However, reads are not guaranteed to be atomic in the same way.  You have to ensure single-reader access (typically by using a single process that is single threaded to read the FIFO; it then isn't a problem at all) while reading the header and then the body of the array.  Allowing separate threads or processes to read the FIFO concurrently could easily lead to chaos.  Think mutexes and/or semaphores.

Comment: I understand that, but considering that inside a struct "int array[]" would be equivalent to "int array[size]" after mem allocation (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221012/unsized-array-declaration-in-a-struct/20221073#20221073), I thought the server would just receive the array as a whole instead of as a pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170918/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-khabz).

Comment: FYI: See the POC code which is working.  It uses the code from `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` which I mentioned and linked to in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround for this: you would need to develop code that serializes and deserializes the `struct` correctly. Both ends must agree on a uniform compiler-independent representation of data being exchanged.

You cannot simply ship a `struct` to another process, because the receiving end may have different different memory alignment and sizing requirements.

The process of serializing the data has three steps:

- Figure out how much memory you are going to need by walking through each pointer in the `struct`, and adding up its size requirements. In your case there is only one pointer, and the size is `p->pref_seats_size * sizeof(*p->pref_seat_list)`
- Allocate the buffer of `char`s to fit your data
- Walk through the `struct` members again, and store the data into the buffer.

Once you get the buffer on the opposite side, allocate the `struct`, walk through the data, and write the data back into the `struct`.

Comment: On a FIFO, it is improbable that there'll be different size or endianness problems — they're constrained to a single system.  (It is possible to have size problems between 32-bit and 64-bit executables on the system; it isn't all that probable.)  It isn't socket I/O.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, I didn't realize it's all on the same computer. Thank you for the comment!