# What is the use of 0-length array (or std::array)?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdarray

In C++11 it allows you to create a `0` length C array and `std:array` like this:

```
int arr1[0];
std::array arr2<int,0>;
```

1. So I'm thinking what is the use of a array that doesn't have a space to store?
2. Secondly what is the zero length array? If it is a pointer, where does it pointing to?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: No, C++ doesn't allow zero-length arrays. Even if it did, it wouldn't be a pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Above code peacefully compiles in `g++ version 4.8.3` with `-std=C++11`

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya add `-pedantic` flag and the first case will be flagged as an extension.

Comment: @ Shafik Yaghmour: you means it is not in standard, even though compilers supports?

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: Yes, many compilers (including GCC) have extensions. Compile with `-pedantic` (or even `-pedantic-errors`) if you want to stick to standard-compliant code.

Comment: An array of 0 length does have a pointer. Just don't try to write to it.

Comment: @d3coy: Indeed, if such a thing were allowed, it would decay to a pointer.  That pointer would be the one-past-the-end pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt One past the end of what?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Past the end of nothing. (But, since such a thing doesn't exist, there's not much point in speculating what it would do if it did.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think it would be better to decay to a null pointer.

Comment: @NeilKirk: So that `(void*)arr` and `&arr` would have different addresses? That would be weird. But, since such a thing doesn't exist, there's not much point arguing about its properties. I'll leave that to the theologians.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well it does exist, just not in Standard C++

Comment: @MikeSeymour: There's no zero-length array **type**. However, there are definitely zero-length arrays: `new int[0]` is valid.

Comment: Why was my comment deleted?

Comment: @NeilKirk: The rules for pointer arithmetic explicitly allow computing a pointer one past the end of the array, e.g. (`a + n` for an array of type `T[n]`).  It doesn't point to an element within the array, so dereferencing it is undefined behavior, but it can be used for pointer arithmetic and comparisons.

Comment: Compiler support many extension, as I explained in my answer, compiling with `-pedantic` is the only way to make sure you know when you are using them. Linux takes advantage of many `gcc` extensions as do other projects which probably forces `clang` to support the same feature set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your first example is not standard C++ but is [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) that both `gcc` and `clang` allow, it is version of [flexible arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20221012/1708801) and this [answer to the question: Are flexible array members really necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001919/1708801) explains the many advantages of this feature. If you compiled using the [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-232) flag you would have received the following warning in `gcc`:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'arr1' [-Wpedantic]

and the following warning in `clang`:

> warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-Wzero-length-array]

As for your second case zero-length `std::array` allows for simpler generic algorithms without having to special case for *zero-length*, for example a template non-type parameter of type *size_t*. As the [cppreference section for std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) notes this is a special case:

> There is a special case for a zero-length array (N == 0). In that case, array.begin() == array.end(), which is some unique value. The effect of calling front() or back() on a zero-sized array is undefined.

It would also make it consistent with other [sequence containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) which can also be [empty](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/empty).