# Is it legal in C++17 to declare an array of size 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, standards, c++17

```
int main()
{
    int n[0];   
}
```

The code above is ok with Clang 4.0.

However, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array says:

> The size of an array must be **a value greater than zero.**

Is it legal to declare an array of size 0 as per the C++17 standard?

Comment: see [What is the use of 0-length array (or std::array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26209190/1708801)

Comment: [More warnings.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EgXzQkeKoGQhdvVK) When it comes to whether something is standard or an extension, `-pedantic` is the appropriate flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it legal to declare an array of size 0 as per the C++17 standard?

No, nothing has changed in C++17 to allow zero sized arrays.  Per the C++17 draft [[dcl.array]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1)

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ constant-expression<sub>opt</sub>] attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>
> [...]If the constant-expression is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type std​::​size_­t and its **value shall be greater than zero**.[...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

What you are seeing here is a non standard compiler extension that is allowing you to compile the code.

You can disable these extensions by using the `-pedantic` compiler flag.

Answer (score 3):

It's "legal" only because it's an extension of gcc and clang. If you compile with `-pedantic` then you'll see that what you're doing is not working with the ISO C++ Standard