# How to pass an array of zero size to template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have an example function which takes a reference to an array. The number of elements in the function definition is unknown.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void someFun(T (&)[N])
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Calling this function for an array of one element is compiling fine.
Deduced param type is `int (&)[1]`.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[1];
    someFun(arr);
}
```

The problem is, when I'm trying to pass an array of zero elements. Example below shows the code and error.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[0];
    someFun(arr);
}
```

Compilation error (using g++ 7.2):

```
../src/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../src/main.cpp:24:13: error: no matching function for call to 'someFun(int  [0])'
someFun(arr);
         ^
../src/main.cpp:9:6: note: candidate: template<class T, long unsigned int N>  void someFun(T (&)[N])
void someFun(T (&a)[N])
  ^~~~~~~
../src/main.cpp:9:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

I assume that deduced template param type is `int (&)[0]`, however the substitution of this argument failed. I can go around by overloading `someFun`. Here is my working example:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void someFun(T (&)[N])
{
    /* ... */
}

template<typename T>
void someFun(T (&)[0])
{
    /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    int arr[0];
    someFun(arr);
}
```

Running this code leads to a call to `void someFun(T (&)[0])` function and deduced param type is `int (&)[0]`. Could you please explain why I can't use more generic solution for an array of zero elements? Please don't judge the reason of this code. It is just an example for learning purposes.

Comment: Note [arrays of zero size are an extension and not standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26209190/1708801) using `-pedantic` to obtain a diagnostic. They are mainly useful for flexible arrays members, they may work by accident in other cases.

Comment: There's no such thing as an array of size 0. The length has to be greater than 0 ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array))

Comment: A c-style array cannot have zero size; it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @max66 It is *not* undefined behaviour, it's simply not allowed by standard C++ and the compiler will give you diagnostic.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned this but `std::array` is well defined for size zero. And honestly, you should not be using `std::array` anyhow, there's very few reasons to still use a C style array.

Comment: @NirFriedman [the content in my link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203358/how-to-pass-an-array-of-zero-size-to-template-function#comment85412131_49203358) mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays of zero size are definitely not standard C++.  From [[dcl.array]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1):

> In a declaration `T` `D` where `D` has the form
>
> `D1 [ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt`
>
> [...]
>
> If the constant-expression is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type `std​::​size_­t` and its value shall be greater than zero.

GCC however provides arrays of zero length as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) but since they are non-standard you can't expect them to work together with other language features, such as template argument deduction.  You could make an explicit overload of the function for zero length arrays.

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void someFun(T (&)[N]) {}

template<typename T>
void someFun(T (&)[0]) {}

int main() {
    int arr[0];
    someFun(arr);
}
```

This compiles on GCC (7.2.0) but not on Clang (6.0.0).

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN That is of course and option but the question was about arrays, not `std::array`.  From the quesion: “It is just an example for learning purposes.”