# Variable size array as class member: why does it compile?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I have this situation which I cannot explain why it compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() {cout << "in X constructor: " << endl;};
};

class Y {
public:
    Y() {cout << "in Y constructor" << endl;};
private:    
    X x[];
};

int main() {
    Y y;
    return 0;
}
```

I am defining a variable size array of `X` as a member of class `Y`. Defining `X` it is such a way outside the class would surely result in a compile error, but not within the class. What’s more, the constructor of `X` is never called.

So what is happening here?

Comment: That's not a variable-length array, but a "flexible array". IIRC, in C, this allows a `malloc` trick, appending arbitrary amounts to a struct with a "nice" array-like interface. In C++, this is a GNU extension of g++ and clang++. See, e.g http://stackoverflow.com/q/246977/420683

Comment: Whats the problem with that explanation: warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union ?

Comment: @remyabel When compiling `int x[]` in `main()` I get compile error: `storage size of 'x' isn't known`. So I assume that `int x[0]` is a zero sized array of `int`.

Comment: Overly lax compiler settings: `error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'x' [-pedantic]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C99, 6.7.2.1/16 (n1256)

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*. In most situations,
>   the flexible array member is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than
>   the omission would imply.

It is not a variable-length array. It isn't anything like a data member, more like an interface to tell the compiler you can access some memory via the name of the flexible array member.

/17

> EXAMPLE  After the declaration:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure `struct s` has a flexible
>   array member `d`. A typical way to use this is:
>
> ```
> int m = /* some value */;
> struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to by `p`
>   behaves, for most purposes, as if `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```

This is not allowed in C++11, but accepted by g++ and clang++ as an extension. As the number of elements isn't known to the constructor of the `struct` (for C++), the constructor cannot initialize those elements (automatically).

Comment: I am compiling the above code with `g++` and `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: @davor *"warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'x' [-Wpedantic]"*

Comment: @remyabel See the example in /17; /16 talks about an *incomplete type*. The zero-length array IIRC was a g++ extension before C99 standardized the flexible array member.

Comment: Yeah, I see no reason C++ shouldn't be able to initialize an array of incomplete type, but they seem to get hung up after converting the `[]` to `[0]` (which is a bit of nonsense really).

Comment: @Potatoswatter Huh? How would you initialize an array of incomplete type? Either the number of elements is not known, or the element type is incomplete (or both). The conversion from `[]` to `[0]` probably follows the [old g++ extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).

Comment: @dyp Sorry, but I still don’t get it completely. All this is about structs and C. How does all this translate to classes which are not part of C?

Comment: @davor It doesn't translate at all! There are no flexible array members in C++. However, g++ and clang++ allow them as an extension. `struct`s and `class`es are pretty much the same thing in C++.